# How do I clear all user defined symbols?

Tags: variable-definitions, symbols, faq, clear, persistence

Is there some way to do this other than going to `Evaluation -> Quit kernel` and firing a new one up?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260217/is-there-a-way-to-clear-everything-before-starting-in-mathematica

Comment: programmatically: `Quit[]` or `Exit[]`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Comment: I've had trouble with `ClearAll["Global``*"]` NOT removing definitions in my own packages (.m files) that I'm developing, but that's exactly what I need to do when I am iteratively refining some definitions -- try 'em in a notebook (.nb file), clean 'em out, try 'em again.  The `CleanSlate` solution below works better for me in this scenario.

Comment: JMO, but it would have been nicer for a simple `ClearAll` which accomplishes this.

Comment: Doesn't work:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Names["Global`*"]
{"A", "contourmap", "contourplot", "expr", "f", "Odd", "opts", "s", \
"t", "uspec", "Vector", "x", "X", "y"}

Comment: @tribbloid `ClearAll` doesn't remove symbols, so it is expected that ``Names["Global`*"]`` returns their names. If you wish to remove them, use ``Remove["Global`*"]`` instead.

Answer (score 46):

In the days when computers were slower, and the kernel took a long time to start up (in wall time), a little package was made to help with cleaning up without having to restart the kernel.

This package is still included with *Mathematica*, and is found in `AddOns\ExtraPackages\Utilities\CleanSlate.m` (within the *Mathematica* installation directory).   It is more complete than `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` in that it also attempts to "unload" packages.  The package documentation is within the package file (don't look for it in the help browser, just open that file).

You can load it with

```
<< Utilities`CleanSlate`
```

When the function `CleanSlate[]` is executed, it will attempt to restore the kernel to the state when the package was loaded.  (This can't be done perfectly, but it's much faster than a full kernel restart.)

The package also has a `ClearInOut[]` function which will clear the previous input and outputs stored in the `In` and `Out` symbols (useful in case you are running out of memory and forgot to set `$HistoryLength = 0` at the beginning).

---

That said, I recommend `Quit[]` (or `Exit[]`) for the safest (and *complete*) kernel reset.  It is worth stating explicitly that *Mathematica* consists of two separate processes: the *Front End* and the *Kernel*.  The Front End is the GUI (the user interface you see on the screen) while the Kernel does the calculations.  The Kernel can be closed and restarted independently of the Front End (also see `Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local`)

It is also possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to quitting the kernel.  [See here on how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209612/695132)

Comment: @Nasser You can check the author and release date in the source.  Well, if the kernel is started from the command line, it's pretty much the same: there's no separate process interface.  But it's still easy to restart the kernel.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've run into a (perhaps) weird behavior of `CleanSlate`. If i launch sub-kernels, distribute all definitions and evaluate `CleanSlate[]`, then little memory is freed. If instead i evaluate `ParallelEvaluate[CleanSlate[]]`, then much more memory is freed. What's going on?

Comment: @Valerio: I guess the package was not updated for parallel kernels, and therefore only cleans up the kernel it runs on. If you use `CleanSlate[]` it runs on the main kernel and cleans up that. If you use `ParallelEvaluate[CleanSlate[]]` it runs on the subkernels and cleans up those. However in the initial state no subkernels are running, therefore running `CloseKernels[]` before `CleanSlate[]` probably is the closest to a kernel restart.

Comment: @celtschk I remember that in v4 times, restarting the kernel could take quite a bit. `CleanSlate` was a fast alternative.  Computers got much faster while the startup time didn't increase that much, so today `Quit` is probably the most convenient way to clear everything.  So it's no wonder that `CleanSlate` is not maintained any more.

Answer (score 24):

I use a shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for `Quit[]`, allowing rapid clearing of all sessions variables.  Here is how you can add this to *Mathematica*:

You will be editing `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.  This is an important system file so be careful.  Start by copying the file you are going to edit from the `$InstallationDirectory` to `$UserBaseDirectory` in the same tree.  This should look something like:

```
\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr
```

Add this to that file being careful to respect commas:

```
       Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}],
               FrontEndExecute[
                       FrontEndToken[
                                SelectedNotebook[ ],
                                "EvaluatorQuit",
                                Automatic
                       ]
               ]
       ]
```

*For version 10 I am using:*

```
Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}], "EvaluatorQuit"]
```

If you do not want a confirmation dialog please see [Rolf Mertig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29/rolf-mertig)'s code in:

- [Customize keybindings without modifying files in the installation directory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68864/customize-keybindings-without-modifying-files-in-the-installation-directory/68871#68871)

There are other keyboard shortcuts you may find useful.  See these for more:

- http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5215/5
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209405/618728

---

Alternatively you may want to use a new context for a Cell or Notebook:

In Mathematica, the current `$Context` defines what [Context](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html) unqualified symbol names belong to.  By giving a new Notebook (or Cell) a unique Context, which is easily done through the `Evaluation` menu, the symbols used in that Notebook will not collide with unqualified symbols in other Notebooks.  See the following question for more detailed information:

- [Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/853/5)

Answer (score 12):

I have the following commands in my `init.m` file, which can be found in `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`.

```
eraseAll := ClearAll[Evaluate[$Context<>"*"]];
eraseAll::usage="eraseAll clears all values, definitions, attributes, messages and defaults associated with symbols in the current context"

removeAll := Remove[Evaluate[$Context<>"*"]];
removeAll::usage="removeAll removes all symbols in the current context"
```

I typically use `eraseAll` to wipe my variables/functions and startover. `removeAll` is used when I want to remove all the symbols from the kernel.

Note the difference between `ClearAll` and `Remove` — the former clears all definitions, attributes, etc associated with the symbols, but not the symbols themselves, whereas the latter removes them completely, so that the kernel doesn't recognize them anymore. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: +1 Username checks out!

Answer (score 11):

I just found that doing `Quit[]` does what I want, too. It may not be the nicest way, but it is easy to remember. Another Mathematica kernel seems to be automatically started when the next command is run.

Comment: @Nasser To be precise, `Quit` restarts the kernel, which means that *all* kernel variables are cleared.  Localized variables of a `DynamicModule` are owned by the front end, therefore they are not cleared (but then they are local, and will never conflict with anything).  However, if you have Dynamic cells in some open notebooks, they might be auto-refreshed as soon as the kernel has restarted, possibly causing some new variables to be defined again.  It all depends on what you put in your Dynamic expressions (it's a bad idea to change global variables from them).

Comment: In this way simply opening a notebook may cause variables to be defined, if dynamic updating is enabled, and the notebook has Dynamic cells that change globals when refreshed.

Answer (score 8):

I usually initiate a unique context for each notebook via the option under **Evaluation** > **Notebook's Default Context** > **Unique to This Notebook**. In this case, you can remove symbols of your notebook's context with this:

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
```