# What does "Tag Integer is Protected" message mean?

Tags: warning-messages

*(Newbie question)*

For every function I define I get this message:

[image]

When I close and reopen Mathematica, and re-enter the function definition, I don't get the message anymore. What does it mean?

Comment: You can see that `f` is already defined because it's coloured black.  You can verify this using `?f` too.  Instead of the drastic `Remove[f]` you can also use `Clear[f]` to clear all definitions, or `f =.` to remove `f`'s value if `f` is a simple variable (in Mathematica terms: it only has `OwnValues` but not `DownValues`).

Comment: @Szabolcs - Thanks again. I should have known better than to use a single letter as a function or variable name :-/. But this was meant to be  a quickie :-)

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node203.html) of some relevance.

Comment: I can't stand seeing the typo ... when you want to define functions with variables (which appears to be what you are doing) you don't use the `=` sign alone. You should be use the [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) `:=` sign: `f[Rx_] := 25 Rx/(Rx+50)^2`

Comment: Nick, I am glad you have chosen to contribute to our site.  However, this isn't really an Answer as it does not directly relate to the message in Question.  You are correct that (usually) one wants `SetDelayed` when defining a function, but this note belongs as a comment, not an Answer.  I know you do not yet have the ["privilege"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of posting comments but if you continue to participate that will change.  For now I am converting your post into a comment on your behalf.

Comment: @Nick you are _usually_ correct in that you want to use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`. But, on occasion, you can use `Set` if you need the right-hand-side to be evaluated, e.g. `f[x_] = Integrate[q^2, {q, 0, x}]`. This is cleaner looking than using `Evaluate`, but with the same effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means you set `f = 156` sometime before you executed that function definition. Executing a `Remove[f]` before your new definition should have fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. But I also got this in a new notebook. Does that mean that the scope of symbols is session-wide instead of notebook-constrained? (Not what I would expect)

Comment: Yes, session-wide. If you want to constrain your symbols to a particular notebook, see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853).

Comment: @stevenvh The kernel state is not specific to the notebook.  You have to restart the kernel to clear its state completely. But if you want notebook-local symbols, you can use Evaluation -> Notebook's Default Context -> Unique to This Notebook.  This option is available since version 6.