# How to restrict global variables to within a given notebook?

Tags: variable-definitions, system-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks)

I assigned a global variable  like `a=10;` It works in all my notebooks, but I want to restrict that global variable to that notebook only.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Notebooks`->`Notebook's Default Context` and select `Unique to this notebook`:

[image]

Now, could you possibly use more reasonable capitalization and punctuation in your questions?