# Is there a convenient way to localize all variables in a new notebook?

Tags: front-end, kernel, localization

I often digress to test some others’ code when working on my own problems. Usually, I have to check if there are conflict variables. Of course, it is not a wise way. By contrast, all the variables in Mathematica documentation center are parallel to the user’s opened notebook, even if they share the “same” name, that’s because they are in different context.

So, how to make the context of a new notebook different from the working one at the time they are opened?If this can be done, I won’t bother to restart Mathematica or clear all my variables to test them.

What’ more, is it possible to prevent the code from crushing the working kernel and front-end, even if there are serious bugs?

I guess that if the notebook can be opened in different kernels and different front-ends at the same time, all the irritating problem will be solved. But I don’t know how to do that.

Comment: The first answer tells you how to set it up to automatically do this.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks a lot. I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

This command creates a new context every time it's run, (from second to second):-

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 CellContext -> StringJoin["context$",
   ToString@IntegerPart@AbsoluteTime[]]]

$Context
```

> context$3573205251`

Comment: Thanks. Well, just as rcollyer said, the problem is duplicate of [link]Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks)