# new kernel for notebook

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, kernel-startup

I know I can create a new kernel for my notebook from the evaluation menu but is there a command for this?  I'd really like some of my notebooks to startup their own kernel as the first line of code.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24455/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so first of all you have to be aware that number of kernels you can use is limited by license.

You can go now to `Evaluation -> Kernel Configuration Options` and create a new one, let's say `"Kuba"`. It will stay on the list for future too.

Now you just need to evaluate in your notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "Kuba"]
```

and this option will be saved in it too so no need to evaluate that line each time.

Comment: And if you want to set the Kernel Configuration Options using commands per WRI tech support you can use the undocumented EvaluatorNames option. For example SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames -> {"Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}, 
 "Kuba" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, 
   "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}}]