# How can I programmatically set a notebook's kernel?

Tags: notebooks, kernel

Is there a way to to change the notebook's kernel without using the menu?

[image]

Comment: Is this the answer? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43900/5478

Comment: @Kuba Yup, couldn't find that

Comment: what about opening the editing window for the kernel's options?

Comment: If you want to set those options programmaticaly you do something like: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66465/5478