# Make File/New/Notebook create a new kernel by default

Tags: kernel-startup

File/New/Notebook creates a new notebook using the same current kernel. Is it possible to make it create a new kernel by default? I know how to create a new kernel manually and set that kernel to my notebook. What I'm asking is how to automate that process so that File/New/Notebook automatically creates a new kernel and uses it.

Comment: How many kernels would you like this to go up to? It's pretty expensive in terms of processors to be making a new kernel for every notebook. On the other hand if you really want this see Kuba's comments here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43900/new-kernel-for-notebook?rq=1

Comment: Also, if you have a normal license, you cannot create arbitrary many new kernels. Usually, the limit is 2 main kernels. If you happen to be in a network with infinitely many licenses, however, this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Summing up, I don't think you can get away in a long run with what you want. But maybe you can, I will give you few ideas to experiment with, there is no the best way as your request is not standard.

---

Maybe it would be enough to to set separate **`CellContext -> Notebook`** for those notebooks?

Based on [Create new notebook at fixed size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100414/5478), it can be done as follows:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, NotebookEventActions :> {
  {"MenuCommand", "New"} :> CreateNotebook["Default", CellContext -> Notebook]}
]
```

In case you really want **separate kernels**, you can create them dynamically:
[How to set up LinkSnooper for monitoring FrontEnd--Kernel communication?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66070/5478)

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {EvaluatorNames, "newUniqueName"}] = {
  "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False
};
```

and then

```
NotebookEventActions :> {
  {"MenuCommand", "New"} :> CreateNotebook["Default", Evaluator -> "newUniqueName"]
}
```

Considering how many new notebooks one may create it is probably good idea to clean/delete the kernel on `MenuCommand/WindowClose` or something. But then you you to recreate it when the notebook is opened. You could you `NotebookEventActions :> Refresh[reinitcode, None]` for that.

Let me know if there is anything I did not cover.