# how to run multiple notebook at the same time using multiple kernels

Tags: front-end, evaluation, notebooks, filtering, kernel

My problem is that the second notebook file opens but waits for the first notebook to be evaluated. I want to execute both file1.nb and file2.nb at the same time. Here is my code.
any idea?

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
    While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb], Pause[1]]
];

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_] := Module[{},
    SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
    Or @@ Map["Evaluating" /. # &, Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
];

UsingFrontEnd[
    nb1 = NotebookOpen["./file1.nb"];
    SetOptions[nb1, Evaluator -> "RemoteKernel1"];
    SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook];
    SelectionEvaluate[nb1];
    NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb1];
    NotebookSave[nb1];
    
    nb2 = NotebookOpen["./file2.nb"];
    SetOptions[nb2, Evaluator -> "RemoteKernel2"];
    SelectionMove[nb2, All, Notebook];
    SelectionEvaluate[nb2];
    NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb2];
    NotebookSave[nb2];
    
  ];
```

Comment: Before executing the notebooks, assign different kernels to the two  notebooks, using the menu option `Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel`.  Note, however, that your license may limit the number of kernels running simultaneously.

Comment: thanks for comment. i did it before.

Comment: Another thing you usually should do is assure that the default Contexts for the two notebooks are different, so that they do not interfere with each other.  I usually use `Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to This Notebook`.

Comment: Since this code runs in a hpc cluster, i don't have access to compute nodes to do this, how can i do this programmatic?

Comment: Good question for which I do not have an answer. If you can get to the Options Inspector you can set many useful defaults, including `Unique to This Notebook`.

Comment: For reference: https://support.wolfram.com/12425?src=mathematica

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43900/new-kernel-for-notebook