# How to automatically open/create/run each notebook using its own kernel?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I am not asking question such as [new kernel for notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43900/new-kernel-for-notebook) where one needs each time to explicitly create and name new kernel, then again issue a command in the notebook to use that named kernel.

This is all too much work. Imagine if I have 10 notebooks. Having to make 10 names each time, and issue 10 commands, and do this each time one starts Mathematica again?

I'd like to be able each time I open/create a notebook, to have Mathematica automatically use a new kernel. One for each notebook.

It can name it anything it wants. I just need to configure this once and forget about it and not have to do it each time.

This is what I do in Maple, which is great.

[image]

I select the "create a new engine for each document". I do this once, and that is it. Each document from now on runs in its own kernel, with nothing else to do. And there is no limit. I can have 20 worksheets all running at same time, each using its own separate engine (i.e. Kernel in Mathematica talk). But I understand in Mathematica there is a limit, and I think it is 8. So when this limit is reached, Mathematica can tell me, unable to open notebook since there are no more kernels available. That is OK.

I find kernel configuration in Mathematica very confusing actually, and I find Maple's is much easier and simpler in this regard.

I searched and could not find an answer so far but it is possible I overlooked one.

How could I set similar configuration in Mathematica?