# How to start another notebook calculation when one notebook is running?

Tags: parallelization

If your first notebook is running and needs a long time to finish, but you still need Mathematica to do other calculation in another notebook.

The second notebook will not start until the first notebook finish its task, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use a different kernel in the second notebook. You can create new ones and choose another kernel under the Evaluation menu.

Comment: I asked [how-to-automatically-open-create-run-each-notebook-using-its-own-kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280490/how-to-automatically-open-create-run-each-notebook-using-its-own-kernel)  on how to automate this, so that each new notebook opened/created runs automatically with its own kernel. But no one knows how to do this or there is no option to do that. So you have to do it manually each time which I find is a  very awkward process.

Comment: Please is there any command so that we can indicate the kernel before running the notebook?

Comment: Read "guide/BackgroundAndScheduledTasks" in the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing the notebooks, assign different kernels to the two notebooks, using the menu option `Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel`. Note, however, that your license may limit the number of kernels running simultaneously.

See more at: https://support.wolfram.com/12425?src=mathematica

Comment: Superb.  Thank you.  I noticed the assignment is persistent: myNewKernel stays assigned to the notebook after closing it and then starting Mathematica up again.  Nice way to run two notebooks simultaneously.