What is the advantage of more than one kernel?
I have a code sample, I want to run it in different notebooks after different modifications. (To be more specific, the code sample is for differential equation solving, and I want to set different initial conditions in different notebooks. ) Someone told me not to run them in the same kernel to avoid errors. Is that correct? If the answer is yes, why does this setting help me?
Note:

I'm not asking about advanced usage of kernel as in "Parallel Computing".

I'm not asking about how to add a new kernel as discussed in e.g. this post.



@xzczd No, If I have a code and I want to run it in two different notebooks by changing the value of some conditions. Someone told me not to run them in the same kernel to avoid errors. I want to understand more about this technical or software issue. Is that correct? and how this will help me.

@znp:  need to understand two concepts:  (1)  Notebook's default context, and (2) Notebook's default kernel.  If you want communication between notebooks, context of both should be "global".  This I never use as changing variable in one notebook changes it in other.  Best to have "Context unique to each notebook".  If they are unique and you set up different kernels  to run each, then you can run both of the notebooks simultaneously and independently of each.  If both use local kernel and you try running them together, first will run and second won't run until first one is finished.

Now the question is clear enough. (Please add this to the body of question for clarifying. ) Then, a quick answer: To some degree, yes. Using different kernels for different notebooks can be useful for avoiding unintentional variable overlapping, because the kernels are fully independent; another benefit is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282555/1871. But: 1. Personally I think a good coding habit is enough for avoiding overlapping/overwriting/pollution. 2. To avoid variable conflicts, using different contexts is simpler, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/853/1871

To prevent variable overlap, do your calculations in 2 different Modules with local variables. Or define a function with a module, that takes the parameters of your calculations as input.
