# Setting individual CellContext for each notebook loses autocomplete suggestions

Tags: front-end, contexts

I'm running *Mathematica* 9.0.1 under OS X.

In order to have separate contexts for each of my notebooks, I used the instructions in the last part of the accepted answer from the following link:

[Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks?lq=1)

To quote the relevant part of the answer:

> "To set this automatically for all new notebooks, open the Options
>   Inspector (Ctrl/Command+Shift+O), and change the scope to "Global
>   Preferences." Then, the option CellContext is found under Cell Options
>   -> Evaluation Options. Change it to "Notebook."

However I've found that after I do this, I lose auto-completion suggestions for symbols that I define in my notebook(s). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No problems with autocompletion for me on OS X. Did you set the notebook context after you already loaded the notebook with variables or before? If the former then evaluate the notebook and try autocompletion again.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I simply quit and restart _mma_, and worked with fresh notebooks

Comment: I confirm the behavior you report. I am also running V.9.0.1. I have found that selecting choice for `CellContext` except `"Global\`"` induces the behavior in question.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for the confirmation. It appears to be a bug.