# Question about variable name autocompletion in $Mathematica$ 9 on OS X

Tags: front-end, version-9, autocomplete

For the command autocompletion, I can simply use <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then use <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to choose the completion. But when I want to autocomplete the local variables I have input, <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works, but both <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> fail to input the variable's name. I have tried to change this behavior with the **Interface** panel of the **Preferences** dialog , but there are no  options I can change. Do you know some easy to make <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> work for local variable autocompletion?

Comment: I have Mathematica version 9.0.1 on OS X 10.9.1, and I find that autocompletion of local variables works when I have the notebook's default context set to be `Global`, but not when it is set to be `Unique to This Notebook`.

Comment: You are right! I just tried and it indeed work when the default context is `Global`. What I met is when editing .m file, and the context is not `Global` but my package. So the problem is the context, what should we do?

Comment: Are you sure you mean control+k and not command+k? Also, what do you mean by local variable? I get no autocompletion options for `Block[
 {hello}
 ,
 hell (*cursor here*)
 ]` when writing it the first time, but the fact that the variable is local does not matter I think. After evaluating the cell, hello is now available for autocompletion anywhere, also outside the `Block`. It seems symbols from the Global` context are autocompleted, no matter the option notebook's default context. If this option is set to unique for this notebook, new symbols are simple not added to Global`.

Comment: Thank you for comment. In my mac it is cmd+k. I have tried `Block[ {hello} , hell (*cursor here*) ]`, and the autocompletion works. By local variable I mean variables appear in Block and Module. I only have the problem when writing *.m file not notebook file.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38092/3066),