# How to import a variable from one notebook to another notebook?

Tags: import, notebooks

I am a new user of Mathematica. I want to import a variable from notebook-1 to notebook-2 where I am currently using. I have searched for Mathematica repository but unfortunately I could not find an answer to my question.

Suppose that I have:

```
var=23
```

in notebook-1 and I want to import **var** into notebook-2.

Comment: If you happen to run notebooks with unique contexts like I do, then a simple `Export[myFileName,var]` in notebook 1 then `var=Import[myFileName]` in notebook 2 would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, notebooks share the same variables.

So when you type `var=23` in one notebook, and open second notebook and type `var`, it will say `23`.

So you do not have to do anything to import the variable.

[image]

To disable this, you need to do

```
Evaluation menu -> Notebook's Default Context -> Unique to This Notebook.
```

And now variables created in the notebook are no longer shared/visible in other notebooks.

Reference

[Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks)