# How to unload automatically loaded packages?

Tags: packages, symbols, clear, guidelines

I know that this has been discussed here ([How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)), but my case is somewhat different. How does one unload packages during runtime that were loaded with the start of *Mathematica*? Occasionally, for deployment reasons, I would like to revert my system to the default state, to check whether a function works in that environment as well. I have a package that starts when *Mathematica* starts, and it contains some modified system symbols too (e.g. extended usage messages for options). Should I include [`` CleanSlate`​ ``](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4718/) in the same `init.m` file before loading my own package and then later refer to it when I want to return to the default *Mathematica* state? Would it revert modified `` System` `` context symbols too?

At the moment I manually have to edit the `init.m` to remove package loading and then the kernel must be restarted. This is quite tedious.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to revert the entire system to some state, then `` CleanSlate` `` may be the best option. If you want to unload a few specific packages though, you can use my package `` PackageManipulations` ``, available [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html). It has a function `PackageRemove`, which does exactly that. It has an accompanying notebook with explanations. Some additional notes on it are in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/8515823#8515823) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443430/update-reload-mathematica-package-after-changes/8443756#8443756) answers. If you want to just clear all the package and sub/package symbols but not `Remove` them, you can use functions `PackageClear` and `PackageClearComplete` from the same package (***a disclaimer*** : *the package may contain bugs*, although I used it successfully many times)

Note that removing all symbols in the package (and subsequently removing its context) - which is what `PackageRemove` does and what you seem to ask for - may be unsafe if other packages use some of those symbols, since those symbols in the definitions of symbols in dependent packages would turn to `Removed[symbs]` and won't be usable any more, in a sutble way. To check that there are no such dependencies, you can use another package I wrote, `` PackageSymbolsDependencies` ``, available from the same place (it also has a notebook with explanations and examples).

Answer (score 9):

The cleanest possible kernel you can get is starting a kernel *only* (no front end) with the `-noinit` option.

`math -noinit`

The front end will evaluate a lot of code when it connects to the kernel.  `-noinit` prevents the kernel from loading initialization files (`init.m`).  I don't believe you can get to a purer state than this unless you start surgically removing components that are practically built in (`Remove`, `Clear`, etc. applied to pre-defined symbols).

Comment: +1 I have a kernel configuration called "SafeMode" that starts with -noinit.  I use it whenever testing code for posting or debugging.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How did you set up the SafeMode kernel? When I do that and choose **Evaluation > Start kernel > SafeMode** from under the frontend, no kenel is loaded.

Comment: @István I use **Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel > SafeMode**.  Please try that and report the result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, so now I figured how to configure and start a kernel, but even if I assign SafeMode to the notebook, and launch it (with correctly passing `-noinit`), and no other kernel is running than SafeMode ... it still loads my `...\Kernel\init.m`.

Comment: @István I don't know why that would be; perhaps it is version dependent.  I suggest you post a Question on the topic.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can't configure a safemode kernel either. Should I add "-noinit" at the end of "argument to MLopen"? but it will still loading init.m as Zachar said. I tried to add "-noinit" to "shell command ", then this kernel just can't start.

Comment: @matheorem This is what my configuration looks like under Windows.  The name "SafeMode" is arbitrary.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ED71F.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you, this works!

Comment: @matheorem Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: @István Incidentally did you ever get this working?  If not would you try explicit configuration shown in http://i.stack.imgur.com/ED71F.png as well?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In v10 I can load a safe kernel with the following changes according to the recent renaming frenzy: `MathKernel` > `WolframKernel`, `-mathlink` > `-wstp`. I also figured out (just now) why my `init.m` was loaded, irregardless of the kernel arguments used: I've had my `init.m` at `$UserBaseDirectory\Autoload\Autoload` instead of `$UserBaseDirectory\Kernel`. It's not clear what these directories are for exactly...