# Is there a system Reset?

Tags: kernel, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)

The normal way I reset the Mathematica kernel to its initial state is through the notebook interface: `Evaluation` menu, `Quit Kernel` item, `Local` submenu, then the `Quit` confirmer button in the resulting dialog box.  I do this often enough that my fingers know the drumbeat: `Alt-V Q L Q`.

But I really need a way to set things back to normal from code.  I suppose I could go

```
ClearAll /@ Names["Global`*"]
```

or even

```
Remove /@ Names["Global`*"]
```

which does much of what I want, but seems really ham-handed to me, and doesn't really guarantee a complete system reset -- at least I don't think.

There is also the ancient `CleanSlate` utility, which I can call from inside a notebook or package, but I have heard rumors that it's deprecated and unsupported:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My attempts to search the documentation and [image: Mathematica graphics] for something resembling `Reset` or `Restart` or `Clean` yielded nothing useful.

Advice?

**EDIT**: In case you're wondering, I want this for unit-testing big Packages, where I want to Reset in the unit-testing scripts so that I can have deterministic values for results of certain `Unique[]` evaluations.

**EDIT**: I found `Quit[]` and `Exit[]`.  That may be as close as we can get.  I do not see any difference in them

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I wouldn't rely on specific numbers from `Unique[]`.  They could very easily change from version to version.

Comment: I'm willing to update my unit tests at version-change boundaries . . . in any event, there might be other good reasons to do a reset.

Comment: You (or anyone else) might find [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/how-to-unload-automatically-loaded-packages) about removing a loaded package from memory useful.

Comment: apologies -- didn't realize it was a duplicate till we got into the answers.

Comment: Maybe I'm too late for the discussion, but the documentation of `Exit` says, "Exit is a synonym for Quit. "

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Does running `Quit[]` do what you want?

Comment: You don't even need the `[]`.

Comment: @BrettChampion I've been wasting my life away! Thanks.

Comment: @Brett doesn't that go against the *Mathematica* paradigm?  Aren't nearly all other actions made with the form `Action[]`?  This seems more like an allowance to placate users coming from other systems than *good practice*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably.

Comment: Some date&time related functions also evaluate without [ ]: Yesterday, Today, Tomorrow & Now