# How to start Mathematica kernel without loading init.m?

Tags: scripting, initialization

Is it possible to start Mathematica kernel from UNIX command line without having the init.m loaded, but not by simply deleting or commenting out it before hand?

If this is a Mathematica script, is it possible to have the script run and by pass the initialization of running `init.m`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(1487)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1487/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html),

> To suppress the loading of kernel initialization files, use the kernel command-line option `-noinit.`
>
> To specify another file to be used for kernel initialization in addition to `init.m`, use the kernel command-line option `-initfile file`, where `file` is the additional initialization file.