# NIntegrate and memory use

Tags: numerical-integration, memory

I wonder why `NIntegrate` uses memory. I have a long integral computation repeated thousands times. The memory use then goes up and speed goes down. I think I spot a problem with the way `NIntegrate` does not clear the memory of its variables.

Here is a simple example:

```
NI[z_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - z], {y, -b0, b0}]

m1 = MemoryInUse[];

For[i = 1, i < 10000, i++; NI[RandomReal[], .5]] // AbsoluteTiming

m2 = MemoryInUse[];

m2 - m1
```

> ```
> {117.606048, Null}
>
> 40405872
> ```

So, it does not clear 40 Mb... How to make `NIntegrate` clear the memory after it execute?

Answer (score 4):

### Update 3

As [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) correctly [states](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91955/nintegrate-and-memory-use/91956?noredirect=1#comment249938_91956) in the comments, without `NIntegrate` we get the same picture as shown in the "Update 2" section. It proves that memory grow reflects temporary memory allocation by `Table`, and `ClearSystemCache[]` does completely eliminate the memory leak.

We can also switch off the caching completely:

```
SetSystemOptions[
 "CacheOptions" -> {"Numeric" -> {"Cache" -> False}, "Symbolic" -> {"Cache" -> False}}];

(*preloading of necessary packages*)
NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y], {y, -1, 1}]; RandomReal[];

(*startup memory usage when all the packages are already loaded*)
start = MemoryInUse[];

lst2 = Table[NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - RandomReal[]], {y, -.5, .5}];
   MemoryInUse[] - start, {10000}];

final = MemoryInUse[] - start;

ListLinePlot[lst2, GridLines -> {None, {final}}]
```

> [image: plot]

### Update 2

With `ClearSystemCache[]` I obtain the following:

```
(*preloading of necessary packages*)
NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y], {y, -1, 1}]; RandomReal[];

(*startup memory usage when all the packages are already loaded*)
start = MemoryInUse[];

lst2 = Table[NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - RandomReal[]], {y, -.5, .5}]; ClearSystemCache[];
   MemoryInUse[] - start, {10000}];

final = MemoryInUse[] - start;

ListLinePlot[lst2, GridLines -> {None, {final}}]
```

[image: plot]

```
Fit[lst2, {1, x}, x]
```

> ```
> 72075.5 + 16.0001 x
> ```

So `ClearSystemCache[]` solves the problem.

### Update

After more careful checking I must agree that there is indeed a memory leak somewhere inside `NIntegrate`. I recommend to report it to the technical support. Consider the following (evaluate in a fresh kernel session):

```
(* preloading of necessary packages *)
NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y], {y, -1, 1}]; RandomReal[]; 

(* startup memory usage when all the packages are already loaded *)
start = MemoryInUse[];

lst2 = Table[NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - RandomReal[]], {y, -.5, .5}]; 
   MemoryInUse[] - start, {10000}];

final = MemoryInUse[] - start;

ListLinePlot[lst2, GridLines -> {None, {final}}]
```

> [image: screenshot]

(*Mathematica* 10.2 on Win7 x64).

---

### Original answer

When you run `NIntegrate` for the first time it loads some .MX files containing implementation of the algorithms required for solving the requested problem. For example in version 10.2 on 64-bit Windows in fresh kernel when I evaluate `NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y], {y, -1, 1}]` the following packages are being loaded:

```
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\Strategies.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\BNFDefinitions.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\Exclusions.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\LevinRule.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\OscNInt.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\DoubleExponentialOscillatory.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\CommonRules.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\MultiPeriodic.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialSimplifiers\Piecewise.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\GroebnerBasis.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\InverseFunctions.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Regions\RegionUtils.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\OscillatoryRescale.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\SphericalBessel.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\Hankel.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\Struve.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\SinIntegral.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\HypergeometricPFQ.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Holonomic\DifferentialRootReduce.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Holonomic\HolonomicLibrary.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\ComplexExpand.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialSimplifiers\Simplify.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\Fibonacci.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Discrete\FourierFunctions.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\Kelvin.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\Nielsen.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialFunctions\HarmonicNumbers.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\KronrodRules.mx
.\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\NIntegrate\GeneralRule.mx
```

Using `FileByteCount` it is not difficult to find that these files have total size 996530 bytes. This is the main reason for larger memory usage after calling `NIntegrate`:

```
m1 = MemoryInUse[]
NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y], {y, -1, 1}];
MemoryInUse[] - m1
```

> ```
> 26437416
>
> 23227232
> ```

So it is not a memory leak, it is just the loaded packages take up some memory. If you really wish to unload them (what was not supposed by the developers, so I do not recommend to do this if it is not strictly needed), you can find some recipes in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1487/280).

Comment: What happens if you `ClearSystemCache[]`? It seems to go from a modest rate of increase to a negligible one.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Does the plot still look increasing if you replace `NIntegrate[];` with `foo;` or nothing? I think it just reflects temporary allocation needed by `Table` to build `lst2` but that memory is not lost -- if you try evaluating the same piece of code multiple times and check the actual value of `MemoryInUse[]` after each time, does it always grow or does it stabilize? Of course, remember to set `$HistoryLength=0` before this experiment.

Comment: @ilian You are right, without `NIntegrate` I get the same picture as in the "UPDATE 2" section. But is it right that without `ClearSystemCache[]` we get infinitely growing memory usage just for caching?

Comment: @Alexey Not infinitely, I believe, since the cache size is bounded (and can be controlled via `SystemOptions["CacheOptions"]`).

Comment: @ilian What option controls the `NIntegrate` cache size? The `"Numeric"` option has suboptions `"CacheTableLength" -> 1021, "CacheKeyMaxBytes" -> 1000000, "CacheResultMaxBytes" -> 
1000000` what seemingly tells us that the cache should not exceed 2 Mb, but as it is seen from the "Update" section the cache size grows up to 8 Mb and there is no sign that it will stop.

Comment: @Alexey `NIntegrate` uses mostly `"Numeric"`; the max bytes refer to the size of a single entry in the cache table but by default there can be up to 7147 of them. Of course, setting `"Cache" -> False` will put a stop to it.