# Memory preserving computation in chunks

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, streams

I would like to do the following:

1. Make a table
   tab1={{i1,b1,c1,d1},{i1,b1,c1,d2},...,{i1,b1,c2,d1},...,{i1,b2,c1,d1},...{i2,b1,c1,d1},...}
   for the given range imin < i < imax.
2. Make some manipulations with its elements to produce table
   tab2={{i1,b1,c1,d1,x(i1,b1,c1,d1)},{i1,b1,c1,d2,x(i1,b1,c1,d2)}}
3. Then produce the table tab3={{i1,b1,c1,mean(x(i1,b1,c1,d))},{i1,b1,c2,mean(x(i1,b1,c2,d))},...}, and free up RAM by clearing tab1, tab2.
4. To join tab3 for intervals (imin1,imax1),(imin2,imax2),...

Could you please tell me how to make this in Mathematica? The code producing tab1 (Tab1temp[imin, imax]),tab2 (tabOutput), tab3 (blocki[imin, imax]) is given below:

```
Tab1temp[imin_, imax_] := 
  Flatten[Table[{i^0.8, j^0.5, k^0.3, RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {i, imin, imax, 
     1}, {j, 1, 100, 1}, {k, 1, 10, 1}, {l, 0, 1000, 1}], {1, 2, 3, 
    4}];
condition = 
 Compile[{{min1, _Real}, {max1, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, \
_Real}, {t, _Real}}, If[min1 < (x/y)^(z*t) < max1, 1, 0]]
tabOutputTemp = 
 Hold@Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}, {min1, _Real}, {max1, _Real}}, 
     Table[{tab[[t]][[1]], tab[[t]][[2]], tab[[t]][[3]], 
       tab[[t]][[4]], 
       condition[min1, max1, tab[[t]][[1]], tab[[t]][[2]], 
        tab[[t]][[3]], tab[[t]][[4]]]}, {t, 1, Length[tab], 1}]] /. 
   OwnValues@condition // ReleaseHold
blocki[imin_, imax_] := Block[{},
  Tab1 = Tab1temp[imin, imax];
  tabOutput = tabOutputTemp[Tab1, 0.2, 1];
  xyzValues = DeleteDuplicates[tabOutput[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]];
  xyzNvalues = DeleteDuplicates[tabOutput[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]];
  ArraysAllNpointsxyz = 
   SparseArray[
    Transpose[{Flatten[
        Nearest[xyzNvalues -> "Index", tabOutput[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]]], 
       Range[Length[tabOutput]]}] -> 1., {Length[xyzNvalues], 
     Length[tabOutput]}];
  TotalOutput = 
   Join[xyzNvalues, 
    Partition[ArraysAllNpointsxyz.tabOutput[[All, 5]]/
     Total[ArraysAllNpointsxyz, {2}], 1], 2]
  ]
```

I.e., schematically,

```
TabFinal={{0,0,0,0}};
For[j==0;j<=50,j++;
tabtemp=Tab1temp[1+10*j,1+10*(j+1)];
TabFinal=Join[TabFinal,tabtemp];
RAMCLEAR[tabtemp];
]
```

where `RAMCLEAR` is some command freeing up the RAM used for computing `tabtemp`.

Comment: I think you should state clearly in the body of the question that you wish to perform the computation in a memory-preserving way. The title "Stream computation" is unclear. Something like "Memory preserving computation in chunks" would be more clear.

Comment: The code for `Tab1temp[imin, imax]` doesn't depend on `imin` and `imax`. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov : thanks, I have addressed these issues. The code has been corrected.

Comment: You could  dump the variable you want to retain (DumpSave), then use "CleanSlate" to purge all variables you created since you read in the package, and then reestablish the variables you want using "Get"

Comment: @DanielHuber : may I please ask you to show the method using an explicit example (please see an update to my question, the command RAMCLEAR)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a good strategy to free memory when no longer needed is to give the variables a local scope. However, when applying this too finely grained, this may cause many costly allocations and deallocations. So one should seek to reuse already allocated memory.

But the best way to safe on memory is to just not requesting it in the first place if it is not needed. ;)

While this is not overly helpful on its own, I try to raise your awareness for such memory issues. On modern machines, RAM is typically the slowest component involved in scientific computation. So even if it is abundant, one should try to minimize its usage.

How much memory you really need depends - of course - on what you *actually* want to do. Let me see if I understood what you are trying to do. You seem to be running through a grid of 3-dimensional points `{x,y,z}`; then you draw 1001 random numbers `t` and count how often the condition

```
bool = Boole[min1 < (x/y)^(z t) < max1]
```

is met. Then you take this numbers of counts (let's call it `count`) and divide it by `1001`.
But you do it in a really complicated way; so complicated that it took me almost half an hour to learn it.
For example, you store intermediate data in the form `{x,y,z,bool}`. Then you involve a `NearestFunction` to figure out where to accumulate the `bool` values, and you do the accumulation by a `SparseArray`. And finally, you use `Join` to grow your return data. This enforces *Mathematica* to hold both the old value and the new value of array to which you want to join the update.

But actually, you want to do just a simple thing for 1001 times  and for each `{x,y,z}`. And all you have to store is the number `count/(n+1)`. Then let's just store this number, not every grid point along with the Boolean value; we can generate the grid points on the fly whenever needed. (And I also doubt that you will use the random numbers at any other place in your program.) This reduces the memory cost by a factor of 4004!

If I am not mistaken, the following function does essentially the same as your `blocki` function; it is just *much* faster and uses a tiny fraction of the memory:

```
cf = Compile[{{imin, _Real}, {imax, _Real}, {min1, _Real}, {max1, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
   Block[{logx, logy, zinv, a, b, c, counter, logmin = Log[min1], logmax = Log[max1], r, \[Omega] = 1./N[n + 1]},
    Table[
     logx = 0.8 Log[i];
     Table[
      logy = 0.5 Log[j];
      c = logx - logy;
      Table[
       zinv = k^-0.3;
       a = logmin zinv;
       b = logmax zinv;
       r = RandomReal[{0., c}, n];
       UnitStep[r - a] . UnitStep[b - r] \[Omega]
       , {k, 1., 10.}]
      , {j, 1., 100.}]
     , {i, imin + 1, imax}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Not that I employed vectorized code `UnitStep[r - a] . UnitStep[b - r] \[Omega]` to count the points that satisfy the condition. Also I tried to minimize the number of `Power`/`^` operations since those are typically quite slow. This is why I employ logarithms (`Log` is typically as slow as `Power`, but we have to called it considerably less often.)

Plus the program is also parallelized over `threadcount` threads if called as follows:

```
n = 1000;

jobs = 100;
threadcount = 4;
jobdividers = Floor[Subdivide[0, jobs, threadcount]];
result = Flatten[cf[Most[jobdividers], Rest[jobdividers], 0.2, 1., n + 1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way you may use CleanSlate to purge one specific variable.

First you must load the package CleanSlate. Then append to the context path some dummy context like e.g. "tmp`". Then create the variable that is later to be purged, in this context. If you now call CleanSlate with this context this variable is purged. Here is an example with figures of used memory:

```
<< CleanSlate`
MemoryInUse[]
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "tmp`"];
tmp`tabtemp = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^7];
MemoryInUse[]
CleanSlate["tmp`"];
MemoryInUse[]
```

[image]