# Delete the current notebook cell using the keyboard

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, keyboard

Is there another way than pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> until the whole cell is selected and then pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>?

If this is not built in, can I create some sort of a global macro to do this and bind it to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23285/how-to-delete-the-current-group-cell-using-the-keyboard) is a more general solution, too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Referencing Szabolcs's answer, here is the code that must be added to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["m", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell], 
        FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["Clear"]
    }]],
```

I chose Ctrl+M at random; change it to whatever you want.

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/880/121) before you edit the file.

Comment: Change `All, Cell],` -> `All, CellGroup],` to delete the whole cell group, such as Input+Output group. Or change it to `All, CellGroup, 2],` to delete the cell group of level 2, and so on.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 21):

I usually press the down key until I get out of the cell, then press shift-up to select it.

Here are two buttons that will select or delete the whole cell for you:

```
select = Button["Select Cell", SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell]]
delete = Button["Delete Cell", SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell]; 
 FrontEndTokenExecute["Clear"]]

CreatePalette[Column[{select, delete}]]
```

I'll leave it to others to set up keyboard shortcuts for these.

I would like to note that these actions don't require the kernel to execute.  If you are going to send them to the front end for direct execution (`FrontEndExecute`), use the versions prefixed by `` FrontEnd` ``, i.e. `` FrontEnd`SelectionMove ``, etc.  You could probably add this version directly to `KeyEventTranslation.tr`, but I don't have time to test it now.

Comment: +1 "I usually press the down key until I get out of the cell, then press shift-up to select it." ... Your Hired - TY. I'm a shortcut fanatic I hate mouse navigation.

Comment: Is there any way to select all code inside the cell (not the cell itself)? (Or should I ask this as a separate question.) (Looking to make a keyboard binding but code for a button should be easy enough to convert.)

Comment: @Kvothe I usually just jump to the beginning with Command-Left, then select to the end with Command-Shift-Right (it may be necessary to press Down a few times).

Comment: @Kvothe Ctrl+. extends the selection. Pressing a few times usually selects everything. Alternatively, End; Shift+Home selects everything.