# How can I delete cells with error messages?

Tags: notebooks

I'm new to *Mathematica* and am unfamiliar with the notebook interface. I haven't been able to delete cells with error messages.

For example, when I try to ask *Mathematica* to compute something, it returns a message like

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

when it fails. Once I see that, instead of proceeding to the next line, I would like to highlight that error message (along with the erroneous command) and delete it. But *Mathematica* won't let me do it.

How do I do this the right way?

Comment: Select the cell you want to delete using the cell selectors, to the right of your window

Comment: You might find [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1964) question useful, too.

Comment: Thank to the both of you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A notebook consists of a collection of input and output lines.

[image]

The output lines are where your results *appear*, they're not the results themselves. You can edit output lines, but then they become new input lines instead. Mathematica will remember the result from the now disappeared output line, and you can always get it back with the function

```
a = Out[n]
```

So, editing or deleting a result only deletes its *representation*, not the content. Even when you deleted a result in the notebook you can always recall it.

**Further reading**
[Notebook basics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NotebookBasics.html) in Documentation Center
[Notebooks and documents](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/NotebooksAndDocuments/NotebooksAndDocuments.pdf) in Tutorial Collection

Comment: +1 as an image tells more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages generated in the notebook use the `"Message"` style from the stylesheet. If you look at the corresponding entry in `Core.nb` (base definitions), you'll find that cells of this type have `Editable -> False` and `CellAutoOverwrite->True`:

[image]

What this means is that you cannot select the contents and edit it (or erase it), which is why your attempts failed. In addition, you don't have to delete your incorrect attempt and try again — you can just fix your mistake (typo/syntax error/whatever) and re-evaluate the input and this cell will be automatically overwritten (and will disappear if there are no errors).

---

Since you're new, you might also find [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8320/5) useful in learning some basic shortcuts to navigate around the notebook.