# How can I convert a formatted text cell to latex code?

Tags: front-end, export, text, latex

I have a formatted text cell, I want to export it as latex. How can I do that? 
Since copy as LaTeX doesn't work, I thought of pasting it into a string and exporting, but it's a no go:

```
 ExportString["Let M be a TM and let \!\(\*FormBox[\(A \[SubsetEqual] \
\*SuperscriptBox[\({0, 1}\), \(*\)]\),
TraditionalForm]\). We say that \!\(\*FormBox[\(M decides A\),
TraditionalForm]\) if \!\(\*FormBox[\(\[ForAll] \\\ x \[Element] \
\*SuperscriptBox[\({0, 1}\), \(*\)]\),
TraditionalForm]\), \!\(\*FormBox[\(x \[Element] A\\\  \[Implies] \\\ \
M(x) = 1\),
TraditionalForm]\), \!\(\*FormBox[\(x \[NotElement] A\\\  \[Implies] \
M(x) = 0. \),
TraditionalForm]\) We say that  \!\(\*FormBox[\(A \[SubsetEqual] \
\*SuperscriptBox[\({0, 1}\), \(*\)]\),
TraditionalForm]\) is \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"decidable\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\) if there is a TM \
that accepts it.", "TeX"]
```

Comment: Just to get the correct string before programming anything: I guess you're missing `\(` before the second `M` and `\)` after the following `A`.

Comment: I pasted it back in. It returns $Aborted.

Comment: The first thing I tried was copying the text cell as LaTeX, but it didn't work. Gave this message: TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of Map[System`FEDump`TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes[System`FEDump`processBoxesForCopyAsTeX[{TextForm},TextData[#1]]]&,<<14>>, if there is a TM that accepts it.] is not supported. >>

Answer (score 9):

When you export the whole cell and not only its content, then you should get LaTeX code which is not one big math-environment. Maybe one easy way is to create a new notebook with

```
nb = CreateDocument[]
```

then you copy your text-cell in it and if you then `Export` is as "LaTeX", you get the correct code. For example, if I have this

> [image]

I can simply use `Export` (or `ExportString` to show it)

```
ExportString[nb, "LaTeX"]
```

and I get

```tex
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

We can use Euler{'}s formula, \(e^{inx}=\cos (nx)+i\sin (nx)\) 
where \(i\) is the imaginary unit.

\end{document}
```

which gives a nice pdf:

> [image]

### Making it usable with a palette

Here is a basic approach how to pack this into a palette.

```
CreatePalette[DynamicModule[{},
  Button["To LaTeX", copyToClipboard[
    StringTrim@
     StringReplace[
      ExportString[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]], 
       "LaTeX"], __ ~~ "begin{document}" ~~ text__ ~~ 
        "\\end{document}" ~~ ___ :> text]]],
  Initialization :> (copyToClipboard[text_] := 
           Module[{nb},
             nb = NotebookCreate[Visible -> False];
             NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[text, "Text"]];
             SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
             FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "Copy"];
             NotebookClose[nb];
           ])
  ]
 ]
```

Now you get a palette with a button and what you have to do is to select the text-cell with the LaTeX code and press the button. Then you have the correct form in the clipboard and can insert it.

For my above example I get

```tex
We can use Euler{'}s formula, \(e^{inx}=\cos (nx)+i\sin (nx)\) where \(i\)
is the imaginary unit.
```

**Acknowledgements:** I stole the `copyToClipboard` from @szabolcs image uploader!

Comment: @M.R. I would love to get some feedback from you. Is it working?

Comment: It is! Thank you.  I'd like this to be a key command such as Item[KeyEvent["y", Modifiers -> {Control}],
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`CellPrint[
  nb = NotebookCreate[Visible -> False]; 
  NotebookWrite[nb, 
   Cell[StringTrim@
     StringReplace[
      ExportString[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]], 
       "LaTeX"], __ ~~ "begin{document}" ~~ text__ ~~ 
        "\\end{document}" ~~ ___ :> text], "Text"]];
   SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "Copy"];
  NotebookClose[nb];
  NotebookCreate[Visible -> False];
  Cell["Copied!"]]]
 ]  but I can't get it to work!

Comment: Do you know how to add arbitrary commands into a item in KeyEventTranslations.tr?

Comment: Just search for `KeyEvent` on this site. We had various question regarding custom commands. Look for instance [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1977/187).

Comment: I know about them, but the examples I have seen only use FETokens and never execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Then this is worth a separate answer. I never tweaked my KeyEvents so this has to be answered by someone else. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, no problem, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my primary thought. Wish it could bring some inspirations.

First suppose we already have a `Text`-style Cell, then use the menu **Copy As** -> **LaTeX**:

[image: img1]

Paste the content into a pair of quotation marks and clear extra line-breaks:

```
str = "\\text{Let }

 ...

 \\text{, but need some text after it.}" // 
 StringReplace[#, "\n" -> ""] &
```

We get strings suitable for math-mode:

> ```
> "\\text{Let }M\\text{ be a }\\text{TM}\\text{ and let }A\\subseteq \
> \\{0,1\\}^*\\text{. We say that }M\\text{ decides }A\\text{ if \
> }\\forall x\\in \\{0,1\\}^*\\text{, }x\\in A\\Rightarrow \
> M(x)=1\\text{, }x\\notin A\\Rightarrow M(x)=0\\text{. We say that \
> }A\\subseteq \\{0,1\\}^*\\text{ is decidable if there is a \
> }\\text{TM}\\text{ that accepts it. And here is an inline complicated \
> formula: }\\sum _{k=1}^n \\frac{1}{f(k)}\\int_{\\alpha }^{\\beta } \
> \\sqrt{g(x)} \\, dx\\text{, but need some text after it.}"
> ```

Then we reverse the "environment":

```
str2 = StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["\\\\text{(.*?)}"] :> "«$1»"]

str3 = StringReplace[str2, 
   RegularExpression["»(.*?)«"] :> 
    If[StringLength["$1"] == 0, "", "\$$1\$"]] // 
  StringReplace[#, {"«" -> "", "»" -> ""}] &
```

Then **Copy As** -> **Plain Text**:

[image: img2]

Past into SE editor:

Let $M$ be a TM and let $A\subseteq \{0,1\}^*$. We say that $M$ decides $A$ if $\forall x\in \{0,1\}^*$, $x\in A\Rightarrow M(x)=1$, $x\notin A\Rightarrow M(x)=0$. We say that $A\subseteq \{0,1\}^*$ is decidable if there is a TM that accepts it. And here is an inline complicated formula: $\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f(k)}\int_{\alpha }^{\beta } \sqrt{g(x)} \, dx$, but need some text after it.

Though looks working, this procedure is very primary and buggy. *e.g.* The $TM$s in the original `Text` Cell are actually in math-mode (*i.e.* inputted after a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>), but they were converted to text-mode when copy as LaTeX. And when the paragraph ends with a formula, it should be take care of with special rule.

Comment: Thanks @silvia for your solution, but I feel that the other one is simpler...

Comment: @M.R. of course~ I absolutely agree with you :)