# How to clear all output cells and run all input cells

Tags: cells, keyboard

I am new to mathematica and I am a little frustrated. There are a few things that I would like to do but I am finding difficult

1. Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells and run all input cells.
2. Use a keyboard shortcut to run all input cells.
3. Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells.
4. Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all variables and definitions from memory (a global clear).
5. Delete current cell with a keyboard shortcut.

I also have no idea how to modify the system files to achieve the desired outcome so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can edit the file `KeyEventsTranslation.tr` to define new keyboard shortcuts. As mentioned by [R.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/r-m) in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7614/31159), you can copy this file from the `$InstallationDirectory` to the `$UserDirectory` and perform those changes in the latter *(see the linked answer for details.)*

Not all combinations of keys will work, since many are already bound by default. You can however comment the corresponding lines in the file to make them inactive and available for other actions.

The following codes are based on the keys `"j"`, `"v"`, `"w"`, and `"x"`, with the modifiers `Control` and `Shift`. These are not bound by default and work well on Windows.

---

1. > Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells and run all input cells.

This can be obtained from points 2 and 3 below by combining the `` FrontEnd`FrontEndExecute ``'s.

2. > Use a keyboard shortcut to run all input cells.

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["v", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
        FrontEnd`FrontEndExecute[{
           FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["EvaluateNotebook"]
        }]]
   ```
3. > Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells.

   ```
    Item[KeyEvent["w", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
         FrontEnd`FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["SelectGeneratedCells"],
            FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["Clear"]
        }]]
   ```
4. > Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all variables and definitions from memory (a global clear).

   ```
    Item[KeyEvent["j", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
         KernelExecute[Remove["Global`*"]],
         MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
        ]
   ```
5. > Delete current cell with a keyboard shortcut.

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["x", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
        FrontEnd`FrontEndExecute[{
           FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Cell],
           FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["Clear"]
       }]]
   ```

---

[image]

---

**References**

- [Rebinding keys to define new keyboard shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7611/31159)
- [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8606/31159)

Comment: This is really good thank you. Just one more question how do I change them to work with macs?

Comment: Also made the changes to the file but it still does not work. I Have a copy of the file here http://pastebin.com/wacMqMMq (note this is in the windows operating system and I changed the "v" shortcut to "m" )

Comment: @AzJ A coma is needed after an `Item[...]`, if another follows. This can be seen from the syntax of the file. Here is a copy of the modified file: http://pastebin.com/StZuT4c3 (the paste expires in 24h).

Comment: @AzJ `Control`+`Shift`+`m` is already used to merge cells. I cannot find a way to supersede this binding, so no new definition associated to this combination is working on my side.

Comment: @AzJ I left `m` in the file, but it should be changed to, e.g, `j`. Otherwise, other modifiers on `m` could work. (I did not try that.)

Comment: Okay thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells and run all input
> cells.
>
> Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all output cells.

I don't think a keyboard shortcut for this exists. Menu item Cell -> Delete all output is your best bet.

> Use a keyboard shortcut to run all input cells.

CTRL+A -> SHIFT+ENTER in a notebook without any weird content.

> Use a keyboard shortcut to clear all variables and definitions from
> memory (a global clear).

Keyboard shortcut doesn't exist for this, `` Clear["Global/`*"] `` or even quitting the kernel with `Quit` are your best options

> Delete current cell with a keyboard shortcut.

What I normally do is arrow down once to go after the cell, press SHIFT+UP ARROW, and then press DELETE. Quick and easy in my day to day use.

Comment: This is useful but I was looking for something more in the vain of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23285/how-to-delete-the-current-group-cell-using-the-keyboard?rq=1 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29258/how-to-fold-output-cells-by-default?rq=1 and so on where the behavior is modified by editing files.

Comment: @AzJ then you may want to look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-select-and-delete-all-output-cells

Comment: Is there a general guide I can use to see how this works in general (i.e. editing the system files for mathematica). As I see these 'tricks' but I have no idea how to implement them.

Comment: Unfortunately I think they are very intentionally poorly documented. Usually in complex situations I end up with what I need by combining content from a couple MSE questions and the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Also I found this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68864/customize-keybindings-without-modifying-files-in-the-installation-directory) useful in answering my own question
Running `Get["http://www.mertig.com/shortcuts.m"]` adds a ton of useful shortcuts.