# Shortcut to erase the line one writes on, equivalent to Ctrl+k for pico?

Tags: keyboard

Every time I make a mistake (and I mess up quite often, since I'm new here), I loose time having to use *the mouse* to delete the traces of my mistakes: the blue vertical lines with the following appearance:
[image]

Well, I'd like to use a shortcut like with *Ctrl* + *k* for editors like Kile, pico, nano, etc. [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) doesn't give it directly.

Comment: It should be possible to map that functionality to Ctrl+k. Check out the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/delete-the-current-notebook-cell-using-the-keyboard).

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So you want to delete a complete cell? That can be done via keyboard. Starting with V10 there is also new Undo functionality.

Comment: Thanks. However **undo** doesn't work after executing something. That makes things somehow irreversible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 10 you can do this with built-in shortcuts. If you edit a cell, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and the current cell-bracket is highlighted. If you hit <kbd>Del</kbd> it get's deleted.

Note that you can navigate to the corresponding In/Out cell using the up- and down-arrow once a cell-bracket is selected. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> marks the parent cell-group. This works through the hierarchy of cell-groups if you like