# How to delete all cell below the cursor in notebook?

Tags: notebooks

How to delete all the cells below the cursor? I want to remove all the cells that are used for experimenting with various function arguments which are typically at the bottom of the notebook.

How do power users typically cleanup code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Second Notebook

Use a second empty notebook to test your code.

### 2. Grouped Cells

Use titles to automatically create a group of cells, which can then easily be selected and deleted.

[image]

### 3. `NotebookDelete[]`

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[][[First@FirstPosition[Cells[], EvaluationCell[]] ;;]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The second solution is great. Creating title with the keyboard shortcut "Alt + 1" and then using the mouse to select the cell and delete. Is there a way to delete the current cell without using the mouse?

Comment: You can use CTRL + . to expand your selection, and then press Delete. However, you can also [define your own keyboard shortcut](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/delete-the-current-notebook-cell-using-the-keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create a button. Pressing the button will delete all cell groups below the cell group  where the cursor is:

```
clean[] := Module[{i = 0},
  nb = SelectedNotebook[];
  SelectionMove[nb, Above, CellGroup];
  NotebookDelete[nb];
  While[NextCell[] =!= None, If[i++ > 10, Break[]];
    NotebookDelete[nb];
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, CellGroup];]
  ]
  Button["Clean", clean[]
]
```

Comment: This solution leaves the evaluated clean function in the notebook. That needs to be manually removed.

Comment: The OP states "delete all the cells BELOW the cursor"

Comment: After evaluating the "clean" method which creates the button and then moving the cursor above the evaluated cell and clicking "clean" button does not clear the cells below the cursor(ie. the evaluated clean method and its output button). I am new to Mathematica and I am not aware of "Module" and most of the functions used in the "clean" method. Is my usage of the "clean" correct?

Comment: If you move the curser to a cell group above the cell with "clean" and "Button", then this will be erased, including the created button,