# Is there some shortcuts to delete a cell?

Tags: keyboard

Just like deleting a line with `ctrl+d` or something else in normal coding, is there some shortcut to delete a whole cell?

Comment: Select the cell bracket (on the far right edge of the cell) and press the Delete key?

Comment: I don't like to use a mouse lol.

Comment: First, press Ctrl+. (ctrl-period) a few times until the cell bracket is highlighted.  Second, use the up/down arrow keys to navigate to the cell you want to delete.  Finally, press Delete.  If you change your mind before you press Delete, cancel the selection using the the left arrow.

Comment: @LouisB Thanks, but seems the shortcut should be `ctrl+shift+.` at least for me.

Comment: Find [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/delete-the-current-notebook-cell-using-the-keyboard) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command below will temporarily put a 'Delete cell' action on the Insert menu which can be activated with `ctrl+k`.  It only persists for the current session.

If your cursor is initially positioned between cells activation will delete the cell below.

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter,
   MenuItem["Delete cell", FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     Module[{nb},
      nb = SelectedNotebook[];
      SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
      SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
      NotebookDelete[nb];
      SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]
     ]],
    MenuKey["k", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

To make it a permanent menu item add the following to MenuSetup.tr.  (Make a backup first though.)

```
Item["Delete cell", KernelExecute[
  Module[{nb},
   nb = SelectedNotebook[];
   SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
   NotebookDelete[nb];
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]
  ]],
 MenuKey["k", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
 MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]
```

I can see myself adopting this useful function.

ref. [How can I set a keyboard shortcut to run a command?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/363)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still have two points unget. First, I don't know the exact place of MenuSetup.tr to add, there are too many `Menu["..."]` inside, and nested. Second, if I use the first command, should I also add it into MenuSetup.tr?

Comment: Hi. You should only add the second command to MenuSetup.tr

Comment: Alternatively, save the first commend as a package, e.g. 'Delete cell.m' and load it with preinitialisation, i.e. set by `InitializationValue[$PreInitialization] = Hold[Get[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Documents", "Delete cell.m"}]]]`
That will load 'Delete cell.m' every time Mathematica is started.  Seems to slow down startup a bit though.

Comment: TextResources\MenuSetup.tr does not seem to exist in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"}]` on version 13 for Macs.