# Command Completion

Tags: front-end, version-8, keyboard, customization, autocomplete

**Note:** As of version 9, this functionality is available and works out of the box.

---

I've a few questions about Command Completion in Mathematica. I recently discovered this feature, and it's really convenient. However, it gets tiring to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> all the time.

Is there a way to turn Command Complete on after every keystroke, like autocompletion is for many programming IDE's?

Or, failing that, to map it to another key like <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which I find much more convenient to hit? I've looked up some internet sources on changing Keyboard shortcuts for Mathematica, but they all seem pretty complicated.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but, have you tried `Ctr-Shift-K`? Then you can `Tab` between fields in a complete expression.

Comment: At least on Windows, you can use <F2> as an alternative to <Ctrl>-<K>. I can't test it right now but I'd be surprised if that didn't also work on other platforms.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `F2` doesn’t work on Mac OS X

Comment: @OleksandrR.You're right, `F2` does work. My `F2` key is extremely small, however, and it's always annoying to hit `F1` when you meant to hit `F2`. I'm using Fedora 16 by the way.

Comment: Version 9 has a completely reworked autocompletion system

Comment: Uf on Windows Autohotkey will allow to map it to any key.

Answer (score 14):

Changing shortcuts isn't that complicated. All you have to do is change one line in the file KeyEventTranslations.tr in a location in your file system specified by this command:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources", $OperatingSystem}]
```

Locate the following line in a text editor and change the key into the one you want:

```
Item[KeyEvent["F2"], FrontEnd`CompleteSelection[True]]
```

I wouldn't use tab, as that already has a built-in meaning.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209612/615464).

Comment: I do not recommend modifying system files.  Instead [make a user copy and modify that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/880/121).

Answer (score 8):

You can also use hotstrings as a way of autocompletion. By using such replacements, words are immediately replaced by another word on typing a space after the hotstring:

```
CreateDocument[{}, InputAutoReplacements -> {"sync" -> SynchronousInitialization}]
```

You can set such replacements globally under `Option Inspector` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>). Of course no one would do it far **all** built-in commands, but it is useful for the more frequent ones.