# Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

Is it possible to program the Front End to automatically format double square brackets without having to type <kbd>Esc</kbd>`[[`<kbd>Esc</kbd> each time? It's awful to have to type <kbd>Esc</kbd> four times for each `Part` expression, and even more annoying to visually parse the unformatted double brackets.

See also this entry in MathGroup archive: [adding a keyboard shortcut for double brackets](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00647.html)

Comment: I edited the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file to add my own shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks Silvia, could you provide details please?

Comment: Assuming you are under win, open the file in a text editor, add a line like 

    **Item[KeyEvent["[", Modifiers -> {Control}],FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After]}]]**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Some approaches are discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327411/) on StackOverflow. Original references to these go to [Szabolcs's webpage](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php) and a [MathGroup posting by Mr.Wizard](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00773.html).

To summarize, you copy the file: `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/KeyEventTranslations.tr` to `$UserBaseDirectory/` (with the same directory tree) and add the following modifications after `EventTranslations[{` in the file:

```
Item[KeyEvent["[", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After]
        }]],
Item[KeyEvent["]", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[RightDoubleBracket]", After]
        }]], 
Item[KeyEvent["]", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After],
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[RightDoubleBracket]", Before]
        }]],
```

These provide the following shortcuts:

- `〚` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- `〛` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
- `〚〛` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Replace `Command` with `Alt` for Windows/Linux and modify the paths above accordingly.

You can also try [Andrew Moylan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7328495), in the same post, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: this is a nice trick, however I couldn't get it to work on a German keyboard. Since the [ and ] keys events are generated by pressing Alt-Gr 8 and Alt-Gr 9 it seems Mathematica does not catch the KeyEvent correctly. Switching over to EN keyboard design works however... Any ideas how to capture Alt-Gr?

Comment: @xslittlegrass It's not a good idea to modify those files, as they can be overwritten by a new version (if you're in the habit of just having the current version). There might be something else going on with your setup if the above doesn't work.

Comment: On my Windows 7 (64 bit) computer using Mathematica 9.0.0.0, I did not need to replace Command with Alt. The code works as written without modification.

Comment: @Rainer It seems `Alt-Gr` is `Command`+`Alt`. I tried to get these commands working with this knowledge with no success. But try typing `Shift`+`Alt`+`Alt-Gr`+`9` and you'll get `()`. These are called "MatchingParentheses" and in the `MenuSetup.tr`linked with `MenuKey[")", Modifiers->{"Command"}`. Which would be`Shift`+`Alt`+`9` on a german keyboard. Unfortunately MatchingBraces {} and MatchingBrackets [] dont work.

Comment: @R.M. does this work for you on v11.1?

Comment: @glS I don't have 11.1

Comment: @R.M. well, it seems to not work for me, but I wasn't sure if it was just me. May it be that something changed in the latest versions that broke this?

Answer (score 12):

Edit the *KeyEventTranslations.tr* file in a plain text editor by adding the following definitions to the first section of the file:

```
EventTranslations[{

(* Custom shortcuts *)
Item[KeyEvent["[",Modifiers->{Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
    "[\[SelectionPlaceholder]]"],FrontEndToken["MovePreviousPlaceHolder"]}]],

Item[KeyEvent["]",Modifiers->{Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
    "\[LeftDoubleBracket]\[SelectionPlaceholder]\[RightDoubleBracket]"],
    FrontEndToken["MovePreviousPlaceHolder"],FrontEndToken["MovePreviousPlaceHolder"]}]],

(* Evaluation *)
```

Note that these shortcuts are set up to use the `"Control"` modifier to insert a *template* for pairs of single/double brackets.

Comment: These no longer work in 11.2 on windows