# What is the comment shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, comment

I went to a Wolfram Technologies workshop a few weeks ago and the presenter showed us a keyboard shortcut that when a block of input is selected, the shortcut puts the block of selected input in `(* comment *)` brackets. I've forgotten what the shortcut is though. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The short-cut keys for various actions can usually be found directly in the menu. Here on OS X you see the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> at the right side under *Un/Comment Selection*:

[image]

As pointed out in the comments for various systems the short-cuts to comment a selection are

#### Mac OS X

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

#### Windows

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- Right click + <kbd>u</kbd> which uses the context menu short-cut

#### Linux

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on a German keyboard

Comment: Unfortunately on a german keyboard it's impossible to get [Alt]+[/]. It behaves like [Alt]+[7] and you'll change the style to "Text".
But somewhere on SE there is a solution for mapping the commands to other keys.

Comment: @Phab: can you tell where on SE I can find this?

Comment: @riddleculous Have a look at these SE topics: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604837/keyboard-shortcut-to-un-comment-out-code-in-mathematica-7), [Link2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts) and [Link3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting/5215#5215). With this information I changed a lot of my shortcuts.

Comment: @Phab: Why not simply use [Alt]+[Shift]+[/]. For me it works even with the German keyboard layout.

Comment: @DisplayName Didn't work back in 2014 ;)