# Switch actions of Shift+Enter and Enter in notebook interface?

Tags: front-end, customization, windows, linux, keyboard

How can I switch the functionality of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combinations in Windows?

I find Matlab's interface more intuitive sometimes. By default in *Mathematica*'s front-end, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> combination processes input in the active cell, while <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a carriage-return.

Is there a standard way to re-map the actions of different key combinations?

Comment: Have you tried `KeyEventTranslations.tr`? On OS X there's an explicit entry for the Evaluate command.

Comment: @Szabolcs no I haven't I have it open now not sure what to change exactly but it looks logical.

Comment: Do make a backup. If you keep the backup in the same location, make sure it doesn't have the .tr extension.  Not sure about how much is shared between Windows and Mac, but on Mac "Enter" and "Return" are considered different keys. "Return" is what we normally use and "Enter" is accessed either as Shift-Return or through the numpad.  KeyEventTranslations uses the same names (Return vs Enter) on Mac.

Comment: @Kuba that's correct I would like to swap the Enter and Shift+Enter keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First move `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file to your `$UserBaseDirectory` in order to not damage installation files. ([Rebinding keys to define new keyboard shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7614/5478))

Open the file and find those lines:

> ...
>
> (* Evaluation *)
>
> ...
>
> Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "HandleShiftReturn"]
>
> ...
>
> (* Input *)
>
> Item[KeyEvent["Return"], "Linebreak"]
>
> ...

and swap `"HandleShiftReturn"` with `"Linebreak"`.

Works on Windows.

Comment: This does not work on linux ;(

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a per cell basis easily?

Comment: @Liam No, you can change each event separately but both with result in a loop: `SetOptions[
 PreviousCell[],
 CellEventActions :> {
   {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
    FrontEndTokenExecute["Linebreak"],
   "ReturnKeyDown" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["HandleShiftReturn"]  
   } ]`

Comment: @Kuba Strangely enough, it works for `PreviousCell[]` but doesn't work for `$FrontEndSession`...

Answer (score 9):

Using Autohotkey the following works pretty well.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class NotebookFrame
  Enter::Send {blind}{shift down}{enter}{shift up} 
  Shift & Enter::Send {enter}
#IfWinActive
```

In case the internals are ever changed you can use the following to get the internal class.

```
Return::
  WinGetClass, class, A
  MsgBox, The active window's class is "%class%".
  return
```

Answer (score 7):

This piece of code should do the trick. It takes effect immediately.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
  FrontEndEventActions:>{{"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
  FrontEndTokenExecute["Linebreak"], "ReturnKeyDown" :> 
FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateCells"]}]
```

(Tested on ArchLinux/MacOS_Sierra/Win10Server2016 with MMA 11. Hopefully it will work on Ubuntu, too)

If you want to run it automatically each time you open MMA, you can modify the code and insert it to the frontend configuration file `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`

And many thanks to Kuba. The comment under his answer inspired me a lot. Without his idea I wouldn't be able to produce this answer.

Comment: EvaluateCells is what numpad enter does, not shift+enter.

Comment: (+1) Works with *Mathematica* 11.0.0 on Win7 x64. After evaluating this the usual (not numpad) Enter evaluates Cell, and Shift+Enter inserts a linebreak.

Comment: Did you take this from Kuba ;)

Comment: @Liam Yes, Kuba is whom the credit should go to : )

Answer (score 0):

For completion this technique seems to work fairly well in ubuntu.

Basically if you open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and edit the file you can make the following 2 lines like the following.

```
key <RTRN> {    [ KP_Enter      ]   };
key <CAPS> {    [ Return        ]   };
```

Now CapsLock functions as the return key in Mathematica and the return key functions as the cellevaluation function.

This isn't perfect but works fairly well and most applications seem to still work well.