# Custom keyboard shortcut. Previous answer is not working in Mathematica 10

Tags: customization, keyboard

I want to remap the alias delimiter from <kbd>Esc</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or some other key combo).  I have not been able to get the previous solution to the question to work ([Rebinding keys to define new keyboard shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts)).

I copied the file, copy and pasted the code (though I changed it to `Control`, `Shift` **[1]**) into the copied KeyEventsTranslation.tr and placed the copy in my directory (full path: `$UserBaseDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr`).  I restarted *Mathematica* and when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> nothing happens.  The Escape key still produces the alias delimiter.

I have also tried changing the "Up" key to move to the next line instead of the previous line (i.e. `Item[KeyEvent["Up"], "MoveNextLine"]`).  That does not work either.  Pushing the up arrow still moves the cursor to the previous line.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

OS = Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (fully patched)

*Mathematica* = 10.3.1.0

**[1]**

```
Item[KeyEvent["f", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
            "\[AliasDelimiter]", After]
    }]],
```

Comment: Did you try to put it at the *end* of `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?

Comment: It seems `f` is the problem. `x` works well, I don't know why some keys are not working with Ctrl+Shift  even though they are not taken.

Answer (score 2):

Note that both `MenuSetup.tr` and `KeyEventTranslations.tr` define keyboard shortcuts, and when a keyboard shortcut is defined in both files, the one in `MenuSetup.tr` takes precedence. Sometimes the keyboard short cut in `MenuSetup.tr` is defined, but not active, and in those situations the identical keyboard short cut in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` will work. So, let's find the keyboard shortcuts defined in `MenuSetup.tr`:

```
System`MenuKey;
Cases[
    Get @ FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
        "MenuSetup.tr",
        "PrivatePathsTextResources"
    ],
    System`MenuKey[Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A","z"], _],
    Infinity
] //Sort //Column
```

> ```
> MenuKey["a",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["b",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["B",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["B",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["c",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["C",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["C",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["D",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["e",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["E",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["f",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["f",Modifiers->{"Command","Control"}]
> MenuKey["F",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["F",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["g",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["g",Modifiers->{"Control"}]
> MenuKey["G",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["G",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["H",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["H",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["i",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["I",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["j",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["k",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["K",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["l",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["L",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["m",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["M",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["n",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["O",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["O",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift","Option"}]
> MenuKey["p",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["P",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["R",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["S",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["t",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["t",Modifiers->{"Control"}]
> MenuKey["T",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["U",Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["v",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["w",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["w",Modifiers->{"Command","Option"}]
> MenuKey["x",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["X",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> MenuKey["z",Modifiers->{"Command"}]
> MenuKey["z",Modifiers->{"Command","Shift"}]
> ```

As you can see, there is already a keyboard short cut for `MenuKey["F", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}]`, and this short cut is active in the menu system, so it prevents the version in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` from working.

As for the "Up" key question, the only thing I can think of is that you have two definitions for the `KeyEvent`, and your new definition was overridden by the later definition.