# Revert new keyboard shortcut for fraction typesetting

Tags: keyboard, version-13.1

After updating to version 13.1 on macOS 12.4, I discovered that the keyboard shortcut for typesetting a fraction (Insert > Typesetting > Fraction) has changed. In previous versions, the shortcut was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, but now is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>. The old shortcut doesn't do anything in 13.1.

I tried following [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7614) to change the keyboard shortcut. To my surprise, line 65 of the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` reads

```
Item[KeyEvent["/", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Fraction"],
```

which is just the old shortcut. So why doesn't the old shortcut work and how can I restore it?

**Edit:** I switched to the US keyboard layout, and the old shortcut returned. The problem therefore seems to be with my keyboard layout (Finnish/Swedish) and feels like a bug to me. I'm reporting this to WRI.

Comment: `ctrl+/` builds fractions for me on my Mac, OS v12.3, MMA v13.1. `ctrl+'` does nothing I can see.  And when I look at the menu item `Insert > Typesetting > Fraction ` it sure looks like `^ /` to me.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for confirming that, the problem seems to be related to my (non-US) keyboard layout; see the edit.

Comment: I see.  I have a non-US keyboard too, but a UK one so there is a familial resemblance.  Of course, if you tell us here what non-US keyboard you are using you might get more useful comments, even an answer, than I can provide.

Comment: I've added the keyboard layout to the question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in version 13.2 the bug has been removed - at least for the German keyboard version.