# How can I change the Un/Comment section keybinding

Tags: keyboard

I want to change the global keybinding of Mathematica 13.2. to something else since on a german keyboard it does not work properly. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Have you seen: `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts`

Comment: I have seen that, but I was thinking that changing one shortcut should be a fairly straightforward task to edit in some settings menu, but if there is not simpler answer I'll have to resort to that. Anyway I found a dirty hack by using the numpad "/", but this is neither practical nor usable on my laptop