# Best way to extract values from a list of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation

Mathematica has *a lot* of list manipulation functions, and, also because I don't work with lists often, at times I'm a bit lost. I'll find a way, but I'm sure it's not the most efficient. Case in point, this list:

```
list = {{x -> -1, y -> 5}, {x -> -1, y -> 6}, {x -> -1, y -> 7}, {x -> 0, y -> 2}, 
 {x -> 0, y -> 3}, {x -> 0, y -> 4}, {x -> 0, y -> 5}, {x -> 0, y -> 6},  
 {x -> 0, y -> 7}, {x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x -> 1, y -> 3}, {x -> 1, y -> 4},  
 {x -> 1, y -> 5}, {x -> 1, y -> 6}, {x -> 1, y -> 7}, {x -> 2, y -> 3}, 
 {x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 2, y -> 5}, {x -> 2, y -> 6}, {x -> 2, y -> 7}, 
 {x -> 3, y -> 4}, {x -> 3, y -> 5}, {x -> 3, y -> 6}, {x -> 3, y -> 7}, 
 {x -> 4, y -> 5}, {x -> 4, y -> 6}, {x -> 4, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 6}, 
 {x -> 5, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 8}, {x -> 6, y -> 7}, {x -> 6, y -> 8}, {x -> 7, y -> 8}}
```

I just need the numerical data, then this function:

```
Transpose[{list[[All, 1]][[All, 2]], list[[All, 2]][[All, 2]]}]
```

gives me the desired result, but it doesn't look good, and I'm afraid of wearing out my <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys.

```
{{-1, 5}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 7}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 6}, {0, 7}, 
 {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, 
 {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, 
 {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}
```

What's the best way to extract the data from the list?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The easiest way is probably something like this

```
{x, y} /. list
```

Comment: You are the minimalist king with maximal kingdom!!

Comment: +1 - This looks like the right solution; shorter doesn't seem possible, and now I see it it makes sense. It just didn't come up in my mind :-( Thanks.

Comment: @PlatoManiac that's Queen, FYI. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I deciphered that fact recently. Thx anyways though..;)

Comment: This method is nice and quick, but just to clarify a distinction which may depend on your use case: `{x, y} /. {}` returns `{x, y}` while `{}[[;;, ;;, 2]]` returns `{}` (from kguler's answer).

Answer (score 19):

I will do

```
list /. Rule[a_,b_] :> b
```

Though less elegant, for large lists replacement using patterns seems faster.

```
list = Table[{x -> RandomReal[], y -> RandomReal[]}, {i, 100000}];
list /. Rule[a_, b_] :> b; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.1530087, Null}

Heike's method

```
{x, y} /. list; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.3340191, Null}

The very efficient one from kguler

```
list[[All, All, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0370021, Null}

If I have to choose, `{x, y} /. list` all the way!

Comment: This answer is being overlooked in light of simpler solutions for the example given, but this is more general and flexible. For instance, if the list had several symbols and you didn't know which was in which sublist (e.g. `list = Table[{Unique[x] -> RandomReal[], Unique[y] -> RandomReal[]}, {i, 
  10^6}]`), yet wanted only the numerical values, then this certainly is the way to go. kguler's answer works here too, but will not for ragged lists. So +1, although I would've used `:>` instead of `->` for the replacement because otherwise, it'll be affected by prior assignments to `b`

Comment: Thanks, Plato, for the benchmark. I also like Heike's solution best, but will keep R.M.'s comment in mind. About that extra 180 ms, well, maybe I can have a cup of coffee while I'm waiting for the result then. :-)

Answer (score 19):

Four brackets:)

```
list[[All, All, 2]]
```

or

```
list[[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Comment: I like your method!

Answer (score 14):

*Mathematica* on the Raspberry Pi or version 10 of the software has a [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) function which works with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)s and a list of rules. The simplest answer to this question is:

```
Values@list
```

Answer (score 5):

While I would actually use `list[[All, All, 2]]` as I have yet to find a case where that is not fastest, you could also do this with `Apply`:

```
Apply[#2 &, list, {2}]
```

I take the comment about wearing out your keys as humorous, nevertheless read this:

[Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5212/121)

Answer (score 2):

This [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46261/undocumented-form-for-extract) form of `Extract` can be used and it is just as fast or slightly faster that `Part` on my machine:

```
Last @ Extract[list, {{0}, {All, All, 2}}]
```

Comment: This no longer works in 10.0.1 or later.