# Removing -> from list of numbers

Tags: output-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to extract values from a list of rules?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/best-way-to-extract-values-from-a-list-of-rules)

If I have a vector v = {x->1.03, x-> 2.01, .... }, and I want to use an element in the list, I can get an element as v[[1]] = x-> 1.03 but suppose I want to get rid of the arrow?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `x /. v[[1]]` ?

Comment: there's no hurry :) - the longer you wait, the better the answers become!

Comment: @rm -rf oy, good catch ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Since `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) will only return the first match, i.e.

```
v = {x -> 1.03, x -> 2.01, x -> 3.02};
w = x /. v
```

> 1.03

you could extract all the values considering the `FullForm`:

```
FullForm[v]
```

> List[Rule[x, 1.03`], Rule[x, 2.01`], Rule[x,3.02`]]

```
w = v[[All, 2]]
```

> {1.03, 2.01, 3.02}

Comment: Table[x /. v[[i]], {i, 1, n}] gave all of them too.

Answer (score 6):

I reckon that by "get rid of the arrow" you mean you want to access only the numbers from `v`.
You can achieve that by using

```
x/.v[[1]]
```

This applies the first replacement rule  given in `v` to `x`. You might want to check out [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in the documentation.

Comment: `achive/.achive->achieve`...

Answer (score 6):

Not really surprising, but educational: The syntax looks confusing to beginners, but it is very well worth your time to get acquainted with animals like `Replace`(/.), `Rule`(->) or `Map`(/@).

```
x /. # & /@ {x -> 10, x -> 40}

(*{10, 40} *)
```

This also works a bit more literally (if not efficently) following your request:

```
{x -> 10, x -> 40} /. (x -> y_) -> y

(* {10, 40} *)
```