# Manipulate strings within a list

Tags: string-manipulation

Let's say I have

```
Solve[x^4 + 3 == 0, x]
```

with output

```
{{x -> -(-3)^(1/4)}, {x -> -i (-3)^(1/4)}, {x ->i (-3)^(1/4)}, {x -> (-3)^(1/4)}}
```

how do i lose the "x->" part of each string within this list and get something like

```
{-(-3)^(1/4), -i (-3)^(1/4), i (-3)^(1/4), (-3)^(1/4)}
```

Thanks for the answers/links. Judging by the answers I realise now that I have formulated my question poorly. I wanted to know how I lose symbols that are in front of a specific symbol. Let's have a look at two more examples:

```
list={a: horse, b: chicken, c: fish}
```

how do I lose "a: ","b: ","c: "

or

```
list2={section 1, section 2, section 3}
```

how do I lose "section"

Comment: Related Q/As: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10524/125) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/125) ...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i have edited my question.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/731) is the canonical post about how to deal with the list returned by `Solve`. The other to examples will have to be justified/the context will have to be further explained, I think.

Comment: öska, my mistake, i've changed it, now it should make more sense ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 lst1 = {{x -> -(-3)^(1/4)}, {x -> -i (-3)^(1/4)}, {x ->  i (-3)^(1/4)},
         {x -> (-3)^(1/4)}};
 lst2 = {a : horse, b : chicken, c : fish};
 lst3 = {section 1, section 2, section 3};
 lst4 = {section1, section2, section3};
 Last @@@ lst1
 (* {-(-3)^(1/4),-(-3)^(1/4) i,(-3)^(1/4) i,(-3)^(1/4)} *)
 Last /@ lst2
 (* {horse,chicken,fish} *)
 Block[{section = 1}, lst3]
 (* {1,2,3} *)
 StringTake[SymbolName/@lst4, -1] 
 (* {1,2,3} *)
 StringReplace[SymbolName /@ lst4, "section" -> ""]
 (* {1,2,3} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The two cases are different but here is something you can try:

```
list = {a : horse, b : chicken, c : fish};
list2 = {section 1, section 2, section 3};

list /. x_Pattern :> Last@x
```

> ```
> {horse, chicken, fish}
> ```

```
list2 /. section -> 1
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

Comment: Your 2nd one is funny because I just was trying: `list2 /. section :> Sequence[]` which only gives `{2, 3}` - and I don't know why the `1` is missing :)

Comment: @eldo Because `section*1 == section` :D

Answer (score 1):

why not simply:

```
sol = Solve[x^4 + 3 == 0, x]

    x /. sol
```

or

```
#[[2]] & @@@ sol

(*{-(-3)^(1/4), -I (-3)^(1/4), I (-3)^(1/4), (-3)^(1/4)}*)
```

for the second Example you can try:

```
list = {a : horse, b : chicken, c : fish}
#[[2]] & @@@ Transpose[{list}]
(*{horse, chicken, fish}*)
```