# Transform a rule to a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

How can this rule

```
a -> {1, 2, 3}
```

be transformed into this

```
{a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3}
```

by way of a function?

Answers [3175](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/extract-values-from-replacement-list?rq=1) and [10524](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/best-way-to-extract-values-from-a-list-of-rules?rq=1) only address extracting values from the right-hand side, so (as far as I can tell) this question is distinct.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "without referring to the symbol/string on the left-hand side explicitly in the code". Can you give an example?  It would be best to have an example input and an example output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
Thread[ a -> {1, 2, 3} ]
```

and

```
Join @@ Thread /@ {a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {4, 5, 6}}
```

You might also be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616).

Comment: How would this be done without knowing that "a" is "a".  In your answer, you refer to "a" in your code.  I'll update the question to make it clearer.  A related question would be:  How do you extract the left-hand side of a rule efficiently?

Comment: @higgy `a -> b` is just an alternate notation for `Rule[a,b]`, so you can extract `a` using `First`, `Part`, `Extract`, etc.  See here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html

Comment: If extracting the left-hand side is a necessary step in all possible solutions to this question, then edit your answer I and will accept it.  I'm also curious as to whether there are solutions that don't require extracting the left-hand side first, i.e., something more direct.

Comment: @higgy You don't need to know the first part of the rule to apply `Thread` to it.  If you have `x = a -> {1,2,3}` then you can just use `Thread[x]`, no need to know what's inside `x`, other than that it's a rule with a list on the RHS.  Can you give an example input and a corresponding example output?  I thought `a -> {1, 2, 3}` and `{a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3}` could be considered such.  `Thread` takes you from one to the other.

Comment: @higgy No, it's not necessary.  I think we're having a communication breakdown.  Why don't you join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?

Comment: In chat.  Any way to freeze this question until after we've chatted?

Comment: This answers my question.  I forgot that `x -> y` could be expressed as Rule[x,y], and therefore be used with Thread.