# Adding elements in the sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I add the elements in the sublists?
For example, if I have the list which is

```
 m={{1,3},{2,3},{4,1}}
```

then, the output that I want is `3+3+1=10`. 
How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `Part` to get the elements from the list, then `Total` to sum them up.

Comment: $3+3+1\neq 10\phantom{}$

Comment: `Plus @@@ (m\[Transpose])` will give you a list of the sums of the various elements of your list.

Comment: `Total[m[[All, 2]]]` adds up the second column of m.  Replace 2 with 1 to get the first column.  Look up `Part`.

Comment: @J.M. which is why this is a tricky question ;-)

Comment: @Sungjin Lee Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: @J.M. base 7? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I suppose so, yes. Still, it's poor form not to explicitly indicate the base! ;)

Answer (score 4):

I thinks the cleanest way is:

```
Total@m[[All, 2]]
```

using <kbd>Esc</kbd>[[<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>]]<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you use it a lot (like me), you can create shortcuts as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting/5215#5215).

Comment: You can use [these shortcuts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5215/5) if you don't like pressing `Esc` every time for `Part` brackets

Comment: Yes, I use it. I put in the post. Tks

Comment: @Murta, I asked the Q on [[ ]] but find all the answers a pain. Can you make a palette button or single front-end command?

Answer (score 1):

Following  @b.gatessucks

```
 Total[m[[;; , 2]]]

  (* 7 *)
```

If you want to sum all components (as @image_doctor pointed out too, sorry I missed that)

```
 Plus @@@ Transpose[m]

 (* 7 7 *)
```

Comment: `Total[m[[All , 2]]]` works as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Last@Total[{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}}]
```

or

```
Total[{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}}]
```

for both components

Answer (score 0):

```
 {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}} // Query[Total, 2]
```

> 7

Unfortunately the current `Query` and associated `Dataset` implementation is riddled with workarounds - this is going to tech support >>

```
{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}} // Query[Total, 2] // Trace // LeafCount
```

> 3175

Anyone interested in a timing study?

Comment: `{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}} // Query[Total, 2] // Trace // LeafCount` results in `697` as of May 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Just For fun.

```
m = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}}; Last[Total[m]]
```