# Can this Part shortcut key be made to work with version 9?

Tags: keyboard

In version 8 I was a frequent user of the "[Use shortcut keys to easily type〚 and 〛](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php)" trick.

In version 9, when I try to make the necessary change to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, the `\[LeftDoubleBracket]` and `\[RightDoubleBracket]` get immediately changed to doubled single-brackets (`[[` and `]]`). And indeed the shortcuts work, but they insert the doubled single-brackets instead of the single double-brackets. How can the brackets' doubleness be preserved in `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?

Comment: This shortcut is the subject of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5215/92).

Comment: You should enter it via a text editor like vim/emacs (or any other). If you edit it via the front end, it will convert it to `[[`

Comment: Yes, it works in v9 without problems. Just use a plain text editor to edit `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.  *Do not use Mathematica to edit that file because it may break it.*  If you did edit it with Mathematica, try to get the original file from the installer and restore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do believe that it should still work under V9, however I personally have added my shortcuts to MenuSetup.tr rather than KeyEventTranslations.tr and they read:

```
Menu["&Typesetting",
{
...  
    Delimiter,
(*My typesetting shortcuts*)
    MenuItem["Matching ()", FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "(\[SelectionPlaceholder])"]}],
         MenuKey["8", Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]],
    MenuItem["Matching []",FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "[\[SelectionPlaceholder]]"]}], 
        MenuKey["9", Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]],
    MenuItem["Matching {}", FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "{\[SelectionPlaceholder]}"]}],
        MenuKey["8", Modifiers->{"Control","Command","Shift"}]],
    MenuItem["Matching [[ ]]",FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[LeftDoubleBracket]\[SelectionPlaceholder]\[RightDoubleBracket]"]}], 
        MenuKey["9", Modifiers->{"Control","Command","Shift"}]],
    MenuItem["My costum format function", KernelExecute[ToExpression[myCostumTypessingFunction[]]], 
        MenuKey[".", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Command"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],
```

This way they are also listed under the menu Insert>TypeSetting> name, along with a helpful reminder of what the shortcut key combination is. The reason for the `\[SelectinPlaceholder]` is so that you can select some code and use the shortcut to wrap it in parenthesis.

Comment: The `SelectionPlaceHolder` tip is great. Thank you.