# Predictive interface eats my Esc key

Tags: front-end, predictive-interface

After updating to version 9, I found the predict interface very helpful except there is a small problem always annoying me:

Consider this:

I have a list `abc = Range[1, 10];` and I want to take part of it `abc[[2]]`.

For the `[[` and `]]`, I like to use the closer version of the bracket (`\[RightDoubleBracket]`) by press key <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image]

In version 9, when I type `abc` I get this drop list of predictions, and the first <kbd>Eec</kbd> key goes to remove the drop list and the `[[` is not correctly typed:

[image]

[image]

So it is possible to make the drop list automatically disappear once what I typed matches the exists variable, so that the first <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is not eaten by the drop list?

Comment: You could uncheck the "Enable autocompletion..." box in Preferences, Interface. Then use Ctrl+K or Shift+Ctrl+K when you want it. My personal opinion is that the automatic autocompletion is a nuisance.

Comment: You could use [an alternative method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5212/121) for entering the `[[`/`]]` characters; it's faster, too.

Comment: Just form the habit of hitting the first escape twice when in this situation.

Comment: @m_goldberg that's what I've done :)

Comment: @DavidPark The predictive interface is actually a very useful thing and if I turned it off, I would really miss it ...  At the same time these types of issues (described in this question) are extremely frustrating.  I assume you (or xslittlegrass) did describe the issue to WRI support in the hope of getting some attention?

Comment: @Szabolcs To each their own. My preference is to have a clean interface - like a blank piece of paper that one is writing on. Mathematica should only write in a notebook what you have asked it to write. It is fine to provide help when it is asked for, say with a context menu item, another thing to push it in your face so you have to swat it away. I liked the completion in Version 8 much better than in 9. It is also a matter of whether you are using Mathematica as a super graphical calculator, or whether you are writing polished documents.

Comment: @Szabolcs Continuing... Polished documents, for which Mathematica has tremendous capabilities, require detailed specification that is beyond the rather shallow suggestions provided by WRI. If it is a matter of obtaining information on related routines, then learn better how to use the DC. It is also possible to design palettes that give quick access to a group of a few hundred commands, seeing what they are, pasting templates and linking to help pages. Presentations also has two such palettes for math functions and programming. A clean interface is possible and still give help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This late "answer" or work-around is based on comments I made on a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34682/5414) to this question which I just revisited.]

To get around this annoyance I have increased the autocompletion popup delay to 0.6 seconds.  This enables me finish typing an existing symbol name and hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key before the autocompletion popup appears to "eat" the key-press.

This has greatly reduced the number of times I end-up having to backtrack to insert escapes.

The popup delay is found in the **Interface** tab of the Preferences dialog, where you enable or disable autocompletion.

You can of course change the value to accommodate your own typing speed.