# Esc-esc for special characters and autocomplete in Mathematica 9

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, autocomplete, input-alias

I recently upgraded to *Mathematica* 9 and have noticed a slightly annoying behavior that I was looking to remedy. In the past I would type special characters, e.g. `\[alpha]`, by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, with escape being shorthand for the `\[AliasDelimiter]` character. Unfortunately, if *Mathematica*'s auto-complete popup has appeared (say for instance if you're typing in a few letters that match a common function name), escape is *also* the key that closes this popup. As a result, the initial alias delimiter character is never input! This really slows down typing significantly as I have to constantly backtrack and re-input special characters.

A very common scenario is when one is typing in an array name (which *Mathematica* tries to autocomplete) and then typing in the double-bracket Part characters `\[LeftDoubleBracket]` with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The only fix I can think of is to either disable auto-complete (which I do like enabled), or to type in special characters with a different hotkey (perhaps the backtick key, <kbd>`</kbd>). Another solution would be to disable escape as the hotkey that closes the autocomplete window. How have others dealt with this issue?

Comment: Depending on the speed of your typing, increasing the autocompletion popup delay may help...

Comment: I use AutoHotkey to overload some key that I do not use (say CapsLock) and I create a double keystroke shortcut that sends `Esc+[[+Esc` to Mathematica.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar That sounds like an excellent solution, what is the option name?

Comment: Good question. The double-bracket thing is particularly annoying.

Comment: My solution to this problem was to train myself to hit `Esc` twice in any situation where the autocomplete popup has appeared.

Comment: @Guillochon The popup delay is found in `Interface` tab of the "proper" preferences dialog, where you enable or disable autocompletion.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Thanks, I guess I assumed an option like that would have been buried somewhere. A delay of about a half second seems to be a good balance.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29776/predictive-interface-eats-my-esc-key