# Apply a function to the current selection in place

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, keyboard, customization

Say a have the function `foo`:

```
foo[x_] := x + 2
```

Like the `Evalution` `->` `Evaluate in place`, I would like to have a keyboard shortcut that replaces the current selection with the result of applying `foo` to the selection.

For example if I have selected `1+3` in a cell with the following contents:

```
2*1+3-5
```

By pressing a keyboard combination, I want Mathematica to replace it with the result of `foo[1+3]` (`6`):

```
2*6-5
```

Comment: @Kuba Sorry I think that would be too cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, so you need to add this `Item`.

```
Item[KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Control}],
  FrontEndExecute[
      FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
                             RowBox[{"foo", "[", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "]"}]];
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Expression, 2];
      FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]
                 ]
    ]
```

#### Usage

> [image]

Select what you need

> [image]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

> [image]

#### Ref:

Here is a tutorial how to add a new shortcut: [Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5212/5478)