# Test whether the selection is a subexpression

Tags: notebooks, boxes

I am writing a button that applies some transformation to the current selection, in a spirit similar to the question ["Apply a function to the current selection in place"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48431/apply-a-function-to-the-current-selection-in-place).  However, I would like to only allow cases where the selection is a subexpression of the full cell.  How?

For instance, if the cell contains "ab+cd" (its box representation is `RowBox[{"ab","+","cd"}]` I think) then the selection could be "b+c", which means that applying a function f to that part would give "a f[b+c] d", unrelated to the original expression "ab+cd".

A naive approach would be to test if `NotebookRead[NotebookSelection[]]` appears within `NotebookRead[First[[SelectedCells[]]]]`.  Some care is needed to cover `RowBox` with fewer arguments, such as `RowBox[{"a","+","b"}]` contained in `RowBox[{"a","+","b","+","c"}]`.  This obviously fails in cases such as "(ab+cd)/(b+c)": if the first "b+c" is selected the test would wrongly consider it as a subexpression.

A slight improvement is to only increase the size of the selection using `SelectionMove[nb,All,Expression]` (rather than directly going to the `SelectedCells[]`), and only allow a limited number of patterns for the relation between the original selection and the bigger selection.  This still fails for "ab+cd+b+c" (both if we work with boxes and if work with expressions).  It also changes the selection, which makes it harder to apply something to the selection.

There may be a way to do things by saving the contents of the `SelectedCells[]`, saving the box expression of the selection and replacing it by a recognizable marker using `NotebookApply`, and comparing the saved `SelectedCells[]` to the new one to find which part changed.  But I am not fluent enough with boxes yet to succeed.

(The following test that boxes can be turned into an expression may be useful: `Quiet[MakeExpression[boxes,StandardForm]==$Failed]` as a preliminary check to filter out crazy cases such as selecting "y)/(a+" in "(x+y)/(a+b)" and thus limit the number of possible forms that subexpressions can take.)

Comment: Possible Issues section of `MakeExpression's` ref page says that `ErrorBox` is generated in case of "invalid or incomplete syntax". Do you need something more than that?

Comment: @Kuba yes, I need to detect cases where the selection is a valid expression but not a subexpression of the full expression.  Most often the code will be used to FullSimplify a part of the expression, so I'd rather not produce results that are different from the original expression just because the user didn't select quite right (eg the example of "ab+cd+b+c" with the first "b+c" selected would wrongly give "a(b+c)d+b+c").

Comment: Then you have to define "full expression". What if cell contains something like: `Module[{x}, x = (a + b)*c; x + 1 ]`. Moreover, `SelectionMove[nb,All,Expression]` only expands selection to the nearest wrapping element so when you do that for my case where only `a+b` are selected, the result will be `(a+b)` selected, still no `c` there.

Comment: @Kuba: I am almost only interested in applying the code to the result of integrals, to solutions of differential equations, etc. (not to code), to have a convenient way of tweaking how Mathematica has expressed such a result.  So in practice I'd like "full subexpression" to mean a part of the cell such that applying `FullSimplify` to it and plugging the result back should give an equivalent result.  Perhaps a more formal definition would be that the `FullForm` of the selection should be a subtree of the `FullForm` of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

*(The full code is at the end of this post, put together into a shortcut `ctrl-|` that copies the cell containing the selection, wraps the selection in brackets, and places the cursor before the brackets so as to allow the user to type some function to apply to that subexpression.)*

My solution is by no means pretty nor bulletproof.  Most checks are done by replacing the selection by a blank pattern and comparing the new cell contents to the old one, both in terms of the boxes and as expressions.  It also checks things like whether the selection is a (standalone) expression.

The first test is to check that the selection does not span more than a cell (and is non-empty).  Any selection within a cell is accepted.  For error recovery it will be useful to save the original contents of the `selectedcells` (which are a list of `CellObjects`) as a (list of) `Cell` expression(s) `cells`.

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
selectedcells = SelectedCells[nb];
cells = NotebookRead[selectedcells];
If[Length[selectedcells] == 1,
```

The next step is to replace the selection by a recognizable marker, obtained using `Unique[]`.  But first save the current `selection` (as `Box`es) as we will alter it.  We also check whether the selection starts with `-` or `+`, either at the "bottom level" of a `RowBox` or in a nested one (improvements welcome): this `extrasign` is used to add `+` when e.g., `-b+c` is selected in `a-b+c`.

```
    selection = NotebookRead[nb];
    extrasign = 
     MatchQ[selection, 
      RowBox[{"-" | "+" | RowBox[{("-" | "+"), ___}], ___}]];
    unique = Unique[];
    NotebookApply[nb,
     If[extrasign,
      RowBox[{"+", placeholderBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]}],
      placeholderBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]]];
```

The `placeholderBox` auxiliary builds essentially `$123[<selection>]` (as boxes) where `$123` is the `unique` symbol produced above.  Thus, `NotebookApply` wraps the selection as an argument of `$123`, with an additional `+` if needed.

Also check now that the `selection` is a valid expression (this auxiliary tests whether the result of `MakeExpression` is an `ErrorBox`).  Presumably I could do that test earlier.

```
    If[validExpression[selection],
```

Set up the various box data: `boxdata` corresponds to the original cell; `newboxdata` corresponds to the cell after the action of `NotebookApply`; `boxdatapattern` is `boxdata` with the selection replaced by a `BlankNullSequence`.  We will check that `boxdata` matches `boxdatapattern` to catch cases such as "b+b" being selected in "b+b^2".

```
     boxdata = cells[[1, 1]];
     newboxdata = NotebookRead[selectedcells][[1, 1]];
     boxdatapattern = If[extrasign,
       ReplaceAll[newboxdata,
        f_Symbol[a___, "+", placeholderBox[___], b___] :> 
         f[a, ___, b]],
       ReplaceAll[newboxdata, placeholderBox[___] :> ___]];
```

The same for expressions: `expr` and `newexpr` are the expressions corresponding to the initial cell contents and the altered ones.

```
     expr = MakeExpression[boxdata, StandardForm];
     newexpr = MakeExpression[newboxdata, StandardForm];
```

Check that the initial `boxdata` matches the pattern obtained by replacing the selection by `___`, that we started with an actual expression (otherwise the project is doomed) and that we got an expression out, which contains `unique`: this catches cases where `$123` got glued with a symbol before it, giving a symbol `a$123`.

```
     If[MatchQ[boxdata, boxdatapattern] &&
       (Head[expr] =!= ErrorBox) &&
       (Head[newexpr] =!= ErrorBox) &&
       Not[FreeQ[newexpr, unique]] &&
```

Finally, the topic of another question I asked, [about MatchQ and Orderless functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112394/matchq-failing-in-some-cases-with-hold).  This last test essentially checks that the original expression matches the pattern obtained by replacing the selection with `___`.  The pattern matcher does not respect `Hold` for patterns containing `Orderless` functions (such as `Plus`, `Times`), so I hide these `Orderless` functions inside `Verbatim`.

```
       MatchQ[expr,
         ReplaceAll[newexpr,
           {unique[___] :> ___,
            (h_Symbol /; MemberQ[Attributes[h], Orderless]) :>
            Verbatim[h]}]]
       ,
```

This is the end of checking that the selection is a nice subexpression.  The rest of the code manipulates cells to write a copy of the original cell back in the notebook, and to replace `unique` by a function `func` (by default `FullSimplify`) so that the user can just do `shift-Enter` to make this common transformation of the input, or can edit `FullSimplify` to something else, in place.  There is also some error recovery to avoid losing data.

Please do not consider the version number as any guarantee of any kind.

```
(*Version 2*)
(*The "FrontEndExecute" business is from
"https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6224"/*)
(*The "CreateDialog" and "FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind" business is
based on
http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/489487 by Kuba Podkalicki*)

Module[
 {unique, nb, selectedcells, cells, selection, extrasign,
  boxdata, newboxdata, boxdatapattern, placeholder,
  pos, func, expr, newexpr,
  doEW, placeholderBox, validExpression,
  errorMultiCell, errorNotExpr, errorNotSubExpr, errorUnique},
 func = FullSimplify;
 System`FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic}]];
 System`FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
   "SubsessionEvaluateCells",
   {System`MenuItem["Evaluate &With", FrontEnd`KernelExecute[doEW],
     System`MenuKey["|", System`Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
     System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]];
 placeholderBox[sel_] := RowBox[{ToString[unique], "[", sel, "]"}];
 doEW := (
   unique = Unique[];
   nb = EvaluationNotebook[];(*todo: 
   several parts of this code need that selection stays static*)
   selectedcells = SelectedCells[nb];
   cells = NotebookRead[selectedcells];
   If[Length[selectedcells] == 1,
    selection = NotebookRead[nb];
    extrasign = 
     MatchQ[selection, 
      RowBox[{"-" | "+" | RowBox[{("-" | "+"), ___}], ___}]];
    NotebookApply[nb,
     If[extrasign,
      RowBox[{"+", placeholderBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]}],
      placeholderBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]]];
    If[validExpression[selection],
     boxdata = cells[[1, 1]];
     newboxdata = NotebookRead[selectedcells][[1, 1]];
     boxdatapattern = If[extrasign,
       ReplaceAll[newboxdata,
        f_Symbol[a___, "+", placeholderBox[___], b___] :> 
         f[a, ___, b]],
       ReplaceAll[newboxdata, placeholderBox[___] :> ___]];
     expr = MakeExpression[boxdata, StandardForm];(*todo*)
     newexpr = MakeExpression[newboxdata, StandardForm];
     If[MatchQ[boxdata, boxdatapattern] &&
       (Head[expr] =!= ErrorBox) &&
       (Head[newexpr] =!= ErrorBox) &&
       Not[FreeQ[newexpr, unique]] &&
       MatchQ[expr, ReplaceAll[newexpr, {unique[___] :> ___,
          (h_Symbol /; MemberQ[Attributes[h], Orderless]) :> 
           Verbatim[h]}]],
      pos = Most[First[Position[newexpr, unique]]];
      SelectionMove[selectedcells[[1]], Before, Cell, 
       AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookWrite[nb, cells, After, AutoScroll -> False];
      SelectionMove[selectedcells[[1]], After, CellContents, 
       AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookWrite[nb, 
       "//EvaluateAt[" <> StringTake[ToString[Rest[pos]], {2, -2}] <> 
        "]", AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookFind[nb, ToString[unique], Previous, 
       AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookWrite[nb, func, All]
      ,
      NotebookWrite[selectedcells[[1]], cells[[1]]];
      errorNotSubExpr],
     NotebookWrite[selectedcells[[1]], cells[[1]]];
     errorNotExpr],
    errorMultiCell];
   );
 errorMultiCell := 
  MessageDialog[
   "The selection is bigger than one cell.  Please choose a smaller \
selection."];
 errorNotExpr := 
  MessageDialog[
   StringForm[
    "The selection `1` is not an expression, please choose a \
different selection.", DisplayForm[selection]]];
 errorNotSubExpr := 
  MessageDialog[
   StringForm[
    "The selection `1` is not a subexpression of the full expression, \
please choose a different selection.", DisplayForm[selection]]];
 errorUnique := 
  MessageDialog[
   StringForm[
    "The expression contains the placeholder `1`, which would \
interfere with the code of EvaluateWith", DisplayForm[unique]]];
 validExpression[
   boxes_] := (Head[MakeExpression[boxes, StandardForm]] =!= ErrorBox);
 EvaluateAt[pos__] := Function[arg,
   expr = HoldComplete[arg];
   func = expr[[1, pos, 0]];
   ReleaseHold@ReplacePart[expr, List[pos] -> expr[[1, pos]]],
   {HoldAllComplete}
   ];
 ]
```