# How can I find out where a key binding is coming from?

Tags: keyboard

Related: [Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting)

In previous versions of Mathematica, I could add these lines to my *KeyTranslations.tr* file, to map Ctrl+[ to [[:

```
Item[KeyEvent["8", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After]
        }]],
Item[KeyEvent["9", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                "\[RightDoubleBracket]", After]
        }]],
```

(I had to modify @rmrf's original key binding, because there are no [ and ] keys on a German keyboard. They're under the 8 and 9 keys, so I mapped those. I also had to comment out the other occurrence of `KeyEvent["9", Modifiers -> {Control}`, in the same file.)

In Mathematica 10, this works for Ctrl+8, but not for Ctrl+9, so I'm guessing Ctrl+9 is bound to something else.

Is there a way to find out where Ctrl+9 is mapped (so I can change it there)? It's not listed under [tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html), and I couldn't find it by grep'ing for `KeyEvent["9"` in the SystemFiles folder

Comment: This doesn't answer your more general question, but Ctrl+9 inserts an inline cell within a cell of compatible style (e.g., `Text`).

Comment: @mfvonh: I just realized that my question was only half true: I did find another `KeyEvent["9"`, in the same file, mapped to `CreateInlineCell`. I commented that out already - but it still seems to be active. Sadly, these `EventTranslations` seem to be completely undocumented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mfvonh's comment told me where to look: Apparently, the `MenuKey` in *MenuSetup.tr* also binds a key to a command. So Ctrl+9 was bound twice, in *KeyTranslations.tr* and again in *MenuSetup.tr*. Once I removed/changed both bindings, I could re-bind Ctrl+9 to ]].