# How to Automate Esc [[ Esc formatting in version 11.2 on Windows?

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

Existing answers given in [automating-esc-esc-formatting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting) no longer work in 11.2 on Windows 7 for some reason. At least I could not make them work.

It was suggested to open new question to find a solution specific for 11.2+ for Windows.

I do not know when the above solutions stopped working. May be they stopped working before 11.2.

But I have tried them all under 11.2 on Windows 7. None of them work. After editing the file (as administrator)

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\FrontEnd
                          \TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr
```

(I made copy of the file first) and putting the code as is posted in the above linked to answers and then starting *Mathematica*, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> does nothing. I just hear a beep.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried both solutions given above. I also tried making copy of the whole tree to `$UserBaseDirectory` instead of making the changes in the `C:\` installation folder. It also had no effect.

The keyboard I have is plain standard Logitech keyboard on USB input device. Nothing special. New keyboard and works fine. The OS is Windows 7 home premium.

Since the solutions in the above answer worked before, why do they not work any more? And how to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> work in order to more easily enter `[[` and `]]`?

Comment: It works for me on Mac, I've been using it since 11.2 came out.  I keep staring at your screenshot and I can't tell the difference from what I used (except that I do not have the 3rd part).  If you made a copy of the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, make sure that the copy does not have the extension `.tr` (or better: just put it in a different folder).

Comment: @Szabolcs OMG! You just answered the question. Yes, I made a copy, and the copy ofcourse had different name `KeyEventTranslations - Copy.tr` but for some reason, Mathematica when it comes up, instead of reading `KeyEventTranslations.tr` where I made my changes, it was still reading the file `KeyEventTranslations - Copy.tr` !  When I moved the copy to a different folder, now it works!  This all makes no sense to me, but it works now. Please feel free to post this as answer. I am sure I am not the only person who will fall into this trap.

Comment: This happened to me once many years ago. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why things weren't working.

Comment: @Szabolcs this is really a bug in Mathematica. It seems to just read the first `.tr` file it finds there or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you edit the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, it is a good idea to make a backup first.

If you create the backup in the same directory, make sure it doesn't have the `.tr` extension.  Alternatively, put it in a directory outside of Mathematica's installation directory tree.

If the backup is left in the same directory and has the `.tr` extension, Mathematica may still read it, which can cause problems (such as the modifications you made not taking effect).