# ListDensityPlot output and other 3d plots appear as black square in Ubuntu 14.04 OS

Tags: graphics3d, ubuntu

When I use `ListDensityPlot` the output is always a blackbox. This even happens when I copypaste the most basic example on the *Mathematica* help:

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All]
```

It seems to be related to the OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, but I have no clue of why or how this happens.

Hey Guys. I know it should be working OK in computers with other OS.

My question is basically if someone has experienced this before and if you have any clue of what it is related to.

Here I add a screenshot in which you can see that not even the ListDensityPlot from the help page work![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVkA.png)

Thanks

Comment: That code works for me (v10.0, OSX 10.10.5). Have you tried quitting the kernel and starting again? What version and OS are you using?

Comment: I don't get a [blackbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4EXB.png). You might add a picture of your output to your question.

Comment: Code works for me too (v10.0, Debian Linux).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: Hey Guys.I know it should be working OK in almost all computers, that is exactly what is puzzling me!!
I am using a recently installed ubuntu linux, and really, I cannot make a density plot work, even the most basic one.

Comment: Is that only the case for `ListDensityPlot` or also for other kinds of plots and `Graphics` objects?

Comment: I am having the very same problem, running Mathematica 10.3 @ Ubuntu 14.04. HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

All boils down well with your code (10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014))

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

On a fresh/new NB you should add `ClearAll["Global`*"]` at the beginning to avoid conflicts. Some reading;

- [How to | Clear My Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ClearMyDefinitions.html)
- [How to | Manage Computations in Notebooks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ManageComputationsInNotebooks.html)
- [Assignments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Assignments.html)
- [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)