# What explains non-working (black) variables?

Tags: syntax

I'm a bit new in Mathematica 10.3 and have had strange problem. Sometimes, variables appear in black and obviously prompt and error when used.

```
D[y[t],t] (*imagine the y in black*)
```

Just changing the variable name or closing the program seems to restart the variable and everything works smoothly. What explains this behavior? Is it an error in my syntax? It's very annoying to have to change variables' names or closing and restarting the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols which do not have a definition are by default colored blue by the syntax highlighter.  However when a Symbol is assigned the highlighter (by default) colors it black.  So in a fresh session we see:

[image]

But as soon as you do something like `y = 1` you get:

[image]

You can avoid this by using [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalY.html), or simply restarting the kernel to refresh the session.

Reference:
 [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/850/121)