# Make a list of large cities in Germany

Tags: geography

I want to  Make a list of large cities in Germany

```
 CityData[{Large, "Germany"}]
```

[image]

but in [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/)   answer is in short form

[image]

How to get the answer like this?

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Comment: Does this still happen after restarting *Mathematica*? What version and OS are you on?

Comment: @J.M. yes it still happen after restarting. I have a windows 10. and *Mathematica 10* .

Comment: Did you make any changes to your `init.m`, or did you change any settings before? Does this happen for other `Entity[]` objects (e.g. the examples in the docs)?

Comment: Check that it is the latest version of Mathematica 10.3.1 . There was a bug regarding the connection to Wolfram Research Data center in earlier versions of 10.

Comment: I try    ` << EntityFramework` `       and it work. but how to make it default?

Comment: @vito don't you have `InputForm` in `$Post` maybe?

Comment: You need to set or convert cell style to StandardForm.

Comment: Try with << Utilities`CleanSlate` and read [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols), i.e. @Szabolcs answer is verry nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
cities = FullForm[CityData[{Large, "Germany"}]]
```

Comment: That will generate the output depicted in the first picture. OP seems to want the output in the second picture.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should go to **Preference->Evaluation** and make sure the setting of **Format type of new output cells** is `StandardForm` as follows:

[image]