# How to overlay ListPlot on a ContourPlot with correct range?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to superimpose a scatter (Listplot) on a contour plot.

If p1 is a contour plot and p2 is a scatter plot imported from some data, how do I plot them on top of each other?

I tried [Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CombineTwoOrMoreGraphics.html) and [Overlay](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) but neither worked. Simply gave the error:

> Show::gcomb: "Could not combine the graphics objects in
>   Show[p1,p2,PlotRange->All]."

Please help. Thank you! :)

EDIT:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[
  Min[0.10376 (x^2.5 + Sqrt[2] y^2.5), 
   0.0964395 (x/100000000000000000000000000 + 8 y^2)], {x, 0, 
   0.75}, {y, 0, 0.75}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, 
  Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Range[min, max, 0.002]], 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]

p2 = ListPlot[{altdata, sliddata}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

where

> altdata = {{0.01, 0.01}, {0.05, 0.02}, {0.05, 0.03}, {0.05, 
>      0.04}, {0.05, 0.05}, {0.11, 0.05}, {0.05, 0.06}, {0.11, 
>      0.06}, {0.05, 0.07}, {0.11, 0.11}, {0.18, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2}, {0.22, 
>      0.2}, {0.24, 0.2}, {0.26, 0.2}, {0.28, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2}, {0.32, 
>      0.2}, {0.34, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.12, 0.2}, {0.14, 0.2}, {0.16, 
>      0.2}, {0.3, 0.25}, {0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.35}, {0.3, 0.4}, {0.3, 
>      0.45}, {0.3, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.55}, {0.3, 0.6}}

and

> sliddata = {{0.05, 0.01}, {0.11, 0.02}, {0.11, 0.03}, {0.11, 
>      0.04}, {0.3, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.15}}

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

Comment: Without showing us what `p1` and `p2` are, we can't help you.

Comment: `Show[ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}], 
 ListPlot[Range[12], PlotStyle -> Red]]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using the code you provided. The Show expression works fine here.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
testData = Prime[Range[25]]
lp1 = ListPlot[testData, PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[cp1, lp1]
```

[image]

but be carefull and check the sequence of `Show`, because **Show uses the options from the first graphic**

```
Show[lp1, cp1]
```

[image]

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, 0, 25}, {y, 0, 100}]
Show[cp2, lp1]
```

[image]

So, `Show[cp2, lp1, PlotRange -> All]` is a wrong call for `Show`, it works without **PlotRange -> All**, because **Show uses the options from the first graphic**.

With your Edit and your Data I get:

[image]

Is that OK with you?

Comment: That is what I tried (and hoped for) but couldn't produce what you just did! Will attempt at it tomorrow (and, update here) when I have access to my lab computer again.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked in a new notebook file! Thanks somuch!

Comment: @fiziksboy, make ClearAll["Global`*"] a habbit see also [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols), your welcome!