# I am trying to graph an ErrorListPlot and I cannot generate the graph

Tags: plotting

I have a series of data regarding times and heights and their corresponding uncertainty. But I cannot get mathematica to generate a graph of the data... Why?

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{.04233, .196}, 
ErrorBar[.001251, .0115]}, {{.079009, .3795}, 
ErrorBar[.001583, .0115]}, {{.113353, .5245}, 
ErrorBar[.004094, .0115]}, {{.172815, .8355}, 
ErrorBar[.001771, .0115]}, {{.220993, 1.0715}, 
ErrorBar[.003427, .0215]}, {{.322136, 1.451}, 
ErrorBar[.008383, .0215]}}]
```

Comment: Have you run `Needs["ErrorBarPlots"]`? (There should be a grave accent after `...Plots`.) What is your `$Version`?

Comment: I have run Needs[ErrorBarPlots`] I have version 11.0 Student Edition

Comment: Maybe try quitting the kernel. Works fine for me under 10.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud learn about some things and some other things:

[Using a Notebook Interface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html)

[Needs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html)

[How do I clear all user defined symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols)

[ErrorListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

ErrorListPlot[{{{.04233, .196}, 
ErrorBar[.001251, .0115]}, {{.079009, .3795}, 
ErrorBar[.001583, .0115]}, {{.113353, .5245}, 
ErrorBar[.004094, .0115]}, {{.172815, .8355}, 
ErrorBar[.001771, .0115]}, {{.220993, 1.0715}, 
ErrorBar[.003427, .0215]}, {{.322136, 1.451}, 
ErrorBar[.008383, .0215]}}]
```

[image]